# The real difference between float32 and float64

Tags: python, numpy, types

I want to understand the actual difference between `float16` and `float32` in terms of the result precision. For instance, NumPy allows you to choose the range of the datatype you want `(np.float16, np.float32, np.float64)`. My concern is that if I decide to go with float16 to reserve memory and avoid possible overflow, would that create a loss of the final results comparing with float32 for instance?

Comment: `float16` is only very rarely used. Most popular programming languages do not support it. The `float`/`double` in Java for instance correspond to `np.float32` and `np.float64`...

Comment: Yes of course you will lose precision and it depends on your use-case if it's a good idea or not. Just play around with some simple arithmetic within the interpreter to get an idea; but don't just use float16 without a good understanding of floating-point math. Side-note: i used float16 before and was happy to save memory; but the use-case was less complex in regards to fp-math.

Comment: Short course:  "It is intended for storage of many floating-point values where higher precision is not needed, not for performing arithmetic computations".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Using float-16 "just to save space" may be an example of premature optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Answer (score 77):

```py
a = np.array([0.123456789121212,2,3], dtype=np.float16)
print("16bit: ", a[0])

a = np.array([0.123456789121212,2,3], dtype=np.float32)
print("32bit: ", a[0])

b = np.array([0.123456789121212121212,2,3], dtype=np.float64)
print("64bit: ", b[0])
```

- 16bit:  0.1235
- 32bit:  0.12345679
- 64bit:  0.12345678912121212

Comment: It’s the preserved (“safe”) decimal precisions, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

float32 is a 32 bit number - float64 uses 64 bits.

That means that float64’s take up twice as much memory - and doing operations on them may be a lot slower in some machine architectures.

However, float64’s can represent numbers much more accurately than 32 bit floats.

They also allow much larger numbers to be stored.

For your Python-Numpy project I'm sure you know the input variables and their nature.

To make a decision we as programmers need to ask ourselves

1. What kind of precision does my output need?
2. Is speed not an issue at all?
3. what precision is needed in parts per million?

A naive example would be if I store weather data of my city as
[12.3, 14.5, 11.1, 9.9, 12.2, 8.2]

Next day Predicted Output could be of 11.5 or 11.5164374

do your think storing float 32 or float 64 would be necessary?

Comment: If I'm only interested in numbers in [-9.999999, 9.999999] range  and don't care about the digits beyond the 6th after the decimal point (I would actually prefer to always round and force-zero them but I know this is not possible as binary floating point format can't represent some decimal fractions without adding some humble remainders) can I use  float16 or float 32 or is it necessary to use float64?

Answer (score 2):

float32 is less accurate but faster than float64, and float64 is more accurate than float32 but consumes more memory. If accuracy is more important than speed, you can use float64. and if speed is more important than accuracy, you can use float32.

Comment: Is it really faster?

Comment: @endolith most GPUs are optimized for `float32`'s. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079906/float-vs-double-on-graphics-hardware) for reference