# Is Using double variable type instead of float a bad habit

Tags: c, types, double, conventions

I have to code C for my college exams and I have practice of declaring `double` variables instead of `float` variables. Is it a bad habit? Can they deduct marks for it? (we never exceed the `float` limit)

I think using `double` is better than `float` because `0.71` is a `double` literal and if we declare `float one = 1.1;` we are converting a `double` to `float`.

Comment: float is generally not recommended unless you're limit by memory or CPU bandwidth

Comment: "Can they deduct marks for it?" How would we know? If you are concerned then ask your professor or whoever will be grading your work.

Comment: In my view, using `float` instead of `double` is more like a bad practice.  The precision of `float` is very limited.  (I also learned C in the days when all floating point arithmetic was done using `double` values — pre-standard C.  But I don't often use `float` — unless I need massive arrays and the reduced precision is acceptable.)

Comment: It depends on a program purpose and target architecture.

Comment: Bad practice is to use types without consideration.

Comment: @Kasun Wathsara Hapangama,  <"0.71" is a double literal> --> In C, there are _string_ literals and _compound_ literals.  `0.71` is neither.  C spec calls that a _decimal floating constant_.

Comment: @Kasun Wathsara Hapangama, <if we did `float one = 1.1;`> --> [When does appending an 'f' change the value of a floating constant when assigned to a `float`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66631288/2410359).

Comment: IMO, this is just a case of bad naming. For integers we have `int` and `short int`, but for floating-point the names became `double` and `float`. Could have been `float` and `short float`, and we wouldn't have had to ask which one if the default, but that just didn't happen.

Comment: `double` has less round-off errors, and `float` displays better. As a general practice, I do all the calculations in `double` but convert to `float` for human interaction purposes.

Comment: Regardless of the chosen data type for decimals, using the appropriate function for that type is essential to prevent precision loss and avoid unnecessary conversions. For example, when working with a float value, it's important to use sqrtf instead of sqrt.

Answer (score 3):

In much discussion on this website, participants [prefer `double` over `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948082/float-vs-double-in-casual-single-computations) and [recommend replacing `float` with `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double) if they see it in a question posed.

> Generally speaking, just use type double when you need a floating point value/variable. Literal floating point values used in expressions will be treated as doubles by default,

People expect floating point calculations on Windows desktops and servers to be [identical between the two floating-point types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double).

> On some architectures, there is no dedicated hardware for doubles, ... giving you a worse throughput and twice the latency. On others (the x86 FPU, for example), both types are converted to the same internal format 80-bit floating point, in the case of x86), so performance is identical.

Some [smartphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622729/double-vs-float-on-the-iphone) and embedded architectures may get a performance benefit from using `float` rather than `double`.

With [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), `float` is [32 bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (24 bit mantissa, 8 bit exponent) and `double` is [64 bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) (53 bit mantissa, 11 bit exponent). The exponent size determines the maximum (and minimum) values for each type. The mantissa size determines the maximum level of precision for each type.

Unless you have a macro for "narrow" floating-point calculations, most mathmatical functions (of the type for which you include math.h) return `double` rather than `float`. A C++ declaration like `const auto cosine = cos(theta)` will declare a `double` called `cosine`. Trigonometric, rounding and exponentiation functions take `double` as parameters and return `double`.

[OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079906/float-vs-double-on-graphics-hardware) is an exception where `float` is often preferred because the API handles floats. With graphics calculations that require precision, you might do your own calculation with `double` and cast down to `float`.

[Should I use double or float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074474/should-i-use-double-or-float)
[What is the difference between float and double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double)

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your question calls for opinion based answers... Let's try to stick to the facts:

> I have to code C for my college exams and I have practice of declaring `double` variables instead of `float` variables. Is it a bad habit?

Not at all. In most situations on modern systems, `double` computations are not noticeably slower than `float` computations and provide better precision and a wider domain.  In special cases, such as interfacing with specialized hardware for video games or neural networks, `float` can be a better or even the only option, but for general problems, `double` seems preferable.

> I think using `double` is better than `float` because `0.71` is a `double` literal and if we declare `float one = 1.1;` we are converting `double` to `float`.

You are absolutely correct about this. The declaration should be written `float one = 1.1F;` to avoid the conversion, although the conversion should be performed at compile time.  Note also that `one == 1.1` would probably evaluate to false.

> Can they deduct marks for it?

This depends on local conventions and the corrector's habits or opinions.  You should ask them what they expect and defend your point orally. It is usually a bad idea for students to go against teachers preconceptions, even if these are invalid, especially doing so in public.