# Uses of the monitor/mwait instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, sse, power-management

I happened to stumble upon these two instructions - `mwait` and `monitor` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait. The intel manual says these are used to wait for writes in a concurrent multi-processor system, and it made me curious what types of usecases were in mind when these instructions were added to the ISA.

What are the semantics of these instructions? Is this integrated through linux into the threading libraries provided by posix (eg. does the thread yield while monitoring a word)? Or are these just fancier versions of the pause instruction? Consequently, what is the relation of these instructions on hyperthreading?

Comment: Fun fact: the other major use is putting the CPU into a sleep state (C-state), with the OS's choice of how deep a sleep.  (vs. `hlt` which just goes into the lightest sleep).  IDK if privileged monitor/mwait is used by the Linux kernel for actual monitoring or not; but user-space versions `umonitor` / `umwait` were added recently to Tremont (next-gen Goldmont atom) https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/tremont and see https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-V3-Intel-UMWAIT

Answer (score 39):

## Uses of `monitor`/`mwait` in the Linux kernel

The Linux kernel uses the `monitor`/`mwait` instructions in the idle loop, which is executed on a core when there is no runnable task (other than the idle task) that is scheduled to run on the core. These instructions are used in the idle loop on all Intel x86 processors, except in the following situations:

- The processor doesn't support the instructions. All Intel Core processors starting with the 90nm Pentium 4, all Intel Atom processors, and all Xeon Phi processors support these instructions.
- The [cpuidle subsystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/pm/cpuidle.html) is disabled (it's enabled by default, but can be disabled explicitly using the `cpuidle.off=1` kernel parameter) or failed to initialize. In addition, the processor is either not from Intel or it's an Intel processor with the `X86_BUG_MONITOR` bug. This bug currently exists only in some Goldmont processors, where a core in low-power C-state can only be woken up via an IPI. See: [x86: add workaround monitor bug](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/7/6/469).
- `mwait` is disabled in the BIOS setup on a processor that supports the instruction.
- The `idle` kernel parameter is used, which takes one of the following values: poll, halt, nomwait. When this parameter is used, the intel_idle driver is not used (i.e., either the acpi_idle driver is used or the cpuidle subsystem is disabled). In the current implementation, nomwait is effectively the same as halt; both use the `hlt` instruction to put a core to sleep (in state C1). (By the way, there used to be a fourth option, called mwait, but it's been removed since v3.9-rc1 because it was deemed not useful. See the patches [1](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/69fb3676df3329a7142803bb3502fa59dc0db2e3) and [2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b253149b843f89cd300cbdbea27ce1f847506f99).)

Otherwise, these instructions are used to put any logical core in any supported C-state (other than the active state C0, of course). This is the case irrespective of whether the cpuidle subsystem is enabled (except as described above), which cpuidle driver is used, and the value of the `intel_idle.max_cstate` kernel parameter (which specifies whether to use the intel_idle or acpi_idle driver and what the deepest C-state is allowed).

A cpuidle driver is responsible for determining what power states can be used for each processor, the performance characteristics of each power state (e.g., exit latency, target residency, and power usage in that state), and how to enter each of these states.

When the intel_idle driver is used, the function that is called to entr a particular state on all processors supported by the driver can be found [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9331b6740f86163908de69f4008e434fe0c27691/drivers/idle/intel_idle.c#L897). It basically works as follows (note that timer interrupts have already been disabled at this point):

- When entering the C3 state or deeper, the TLB entries of the logical core are flushed, so that the core doesn't get woken up just to handle TLB shootdowns.
- If the processor has the `X86_BUG_CLFLUSH_MONITOR` bug, `clflush` is used to flush the address range armed by the `monitor` instruction used to exit the sleep state. To my knowledge, the only processor that has this bug is the Intel Xeon Processor 7400 (the bug and the flush workaround are documented in the AAI65 erratum).
- The `monitor` instruction is executed with `ecx` and `edx` both zero.
- The buffers that are vulnerable to MDS attacks are flushed (if any). For more information, see [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d396360acdf7e57edcd9e2d080343b0353d65d63/Documentation/x86/mds.rst).
- The `mwait` instruction is executed with `eax` containing the target C-state and `ecx` containing 1 (i.e., exit the state on an interrupt).

When the intel_idle driver is not used (i.e., either acpi_idle is used or the cpuidle subsystem is disabled), the [sequence](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8ff468c29e9a9c3afe9152c10c7b141343270bf3/arch/x86/kernel/process.c#L684) is similar, except that the TLB entries of the core are not flushed. Also the target C-state in `eax` is always C1.

(You can use the `cpupower idle-info` and `cpupower monitor` tools to determine the C-states supported by your processor, which cpuidle driver and governor are active, and some performance and usage characteristics (per core) of each C-state.)

Another case where `mwait` is used is when soft-offlining a CPU. The way it's used here is similar to what I've discussed for the idle loop (see the [code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/31cc088a4f5d83481c6f5041bd6eb06115b974af/arch/x86/kernel/smpboot.c#L1703)). A CPU is offlined by putting it in the deepest available sleep state. (One important difference though is that all dirty cache lines in the private caches of the physical core that contains the logical core being offlined must be flushed or at least written back. The reason for this (according to [this](https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-devel/2011-03/msg00816.html) thread) is that cache coherency doesn't work on the private caches if a physical core that is in a C-state deeper than C1. The relevant patch can be found [here](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1009.2/00873.html).)

When waking up the system from hibernation, some of the processors may be configured as offline (e.g., when SMT is disabled, all sibling logical cores must be offline). The cores that were offline before hibernation will still be in the same sleep state when waking up the system, except for the bootstrap processor (BSP). In particular, they can still be woken up by writing to an address in the memory range armed the `monitor` instruction on the respective cores. To make sure that none of these cores are woken up prematurely (before it's possible to perform address translation to fetch and execute the instruction that follows `mwait`), the BSP [wakes up all the cores](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9331b6740f86163908de69f4008e434fe0c27691/arch/x86/power/cpu.c#L309), and then puts them offline using the `hlt` instruction instead. This is not efficient power-wise (because `hlt` puts the core in C1 only), but is safe correctness-wise. Later, all cores that are supposed to be offline are [woken up again and put to deepest sleep](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d4425649c63018e96e5402807c9e7bc5272f7b3b/arch/x86/power/hibernate.c#L251) using `mwait` in a safe fashion. This is an example of why you'd want to use `hlt` instead of `mwait`, even when `mwait` is supported.

The AMD Excavator microarchitecture and later support a variant of `mwait`, called `mwaitx`, which can be configured with 32-bit timer that counts at the TSC frequency and exits the sleep state when the timer expires. Currently, this instruction is only used to [implement the delay APIs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/948a64995aca6820abefd17f1a4258f5835c5ad9/arch/x86/lib/delay.c#L93) including `udelay` and `ndelay`. If this instruction is not supported, the delay is implemented by spinning in a loop until the value in the TSC register has increased by about the required number of cycles. The `pause` instruction is similar, except that sleep time is not configurable.

(Modern Intel processors seem to support timed `mwait` as well, although I don't think this feature is officially documented by Intel for any of the current processors. Perhaps this explains why the Linux kernel doesn't use it.)

Usually, a core transitions to one of the sleep C-states only on-demand i.e., when it goes offline. It's possible to force a CPU package to be in the package C-state for a specific amount of percentage of time, even if there are runnable threads that can be scheduled on cores of that package. The [Intel Powerclamp driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/22051d9c4a57d3b4a8b5a7407efc80c71c7bfb16/Documentation/thermal/intel_powerclamp.rst) can be used to achieve this via the `monitor`/`mwait` instructions.

These are all the uses of these instructions in the Linux kernel that I'm aware of.

## Uses of `monitor`/`mwait` for thread synchronization

Starting with gcc 9 and kernel v5.3-rc1, the user-mode versions of `mwait` and `monitor`, called `umwait` and `umonitor`, are exposed through the [_umwait](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=UMWAIT&expand=5980) and [_umonitor](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=Umo&expand=5980,5979) intrinsics. To use these intrinsics, include the `immintrin.h` header and compile with `-mwaitpkg`. No current processor supports these instructions (the CPUID information in Tremont is correct and the current Intel documentation is wrong about this). The first microarchitecture to support these instructions will probably be Sapphire Rapids. `umwait` is much less powerful than `mwait` and its exact behavior can be controlled by the OS through the `IA32_UMWAIT_CONTROL` MSR. glibc currently doesn't use these instructions.

I think `umwait` is useful for implementing spinlocks and condition variables, where you want threads to block until the memory location that holds the lock is modified (indicating that the lock has been released). In contrast to `mwait`, the timer-triggered wakeup is documented for `umwait`. When implementing a synchronization primitive using `umwait`, it's important to remember that resuming execution from `umwait` doesn't necessarily mean that the condition a thread is waiting for is triggered. `umwait` may wake up due to an interrupt, an expiration of the time limit specified by `umwait` (which could be overridden by an OS time limit), or other implementation-dependent events. Also if `umonitor` failed to arm the address range of the primitive, `umwait` will not even change the C-state. That's why after waking up from `umwait`, the thread must still perform the necessary checks.

`umwait` currently supports only two C-states: C0.1 (called light-weight power/performance optimized state) and C0.2 (called improved power/performance
optimized state). Both of which are not sleep states. They are basically sub-states of C0. This is similar to `pause`/`tpause`, which keep the core in C0. The meaning of C0.1 and C0.2 is currently not documented. I think these sub-states save power by de-pipelining the thread i.e., instructions are not longer fetched for that thread. They can also improve the performance of the other sibling thread because it can now use all of the competitively shared resources without contention. However, partitioned resources are not recombined (which occurs when transitioning to a deeper C-state).

`umwait` is essentially `tpause` + the "memory wait" feature of `mwait` + it causes a transactional abort, like `pause`, when executed in a transactional region. It's worth noting here that the `pause` latency is implementation-dependent (it could be zero), which makes it [hard to use effectively](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/13388). I think the only advantage of `pause` is that it's highly portable; it's supported on the 130nm Pentium 4 and later and it behaves like a `nop` on all 32-bit and 64-bit Intel and AMD processors that don't support it.

Knights Landing and Knights Mill offer [a feature that allows `monitor` and `mwait` to be executed in any ring](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/10/06/intel-xeon-phi-product-family-x200-knl-user-mode-ring-3-monitor-and-mwait) including user-mode. This can be achieved by setting `MISC_FEATURE_ENABLES[1]` to 1. Linux enables this feature by default on these processors. It can be disabled by passing `ring3mwait=disable` to the kernel command line (which makes the kernel not set `MISC_FEATURE_ENABLES[1]` to 1, thereby keeping it at the default 0 value). According to the docs:

> If MWAIT is executed when CPL > 0 or in virtual-8086 mode, and if EAX
> indicates a C-state other than C0 or C1, the instruction operates as
> if EAX indicated the C-state C1.

Interestingly, `mwait` here can be used to transition to C1, but `umwait` can't.

I don't know if this feature on KNL/KNM is used in any program.

Some discussion on the potential of using `mwait` and `monitor` for thread synchronization can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/310436) and [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4536358) (both of which are very old).

## Execution characteristics of `monitor`/`mwait`

Both `hlt` and `mwait` can be used to enter C1. In this case, the only *architectural* difference between them (other than they are different instructions) is that following an SMI interrupt, if auto halt restart is enabled, the saved instruction pointer points to the `hlt` instruction, not the instruction that follows it. So if the interrupt handler wants to return the core to the sleep state, it can just return normally without having to do anything extra. According to 34.10 of Volume 3:

> If the HLT instruction is restarted, the processor will generate a
> memory access to fetch the HLT instruction (if it is not in the
> internal cache), and execute a HLT bus transaction. This behavior
> results in multiple HLT bus transactions for the same HLT instruction.

This also applies to AMD processors.

When a logical core enters a sleep state, all resources that are partitioned or reserved for it become available for the sibling core. At the very least, this may improve the performance of the sibling core (in contrast to using a polling loop). If the other sibling core also enters a sleep state, the whole physical core can enter a low-power state. If all physical cores of the same package enter a sleep state, the whole package (including the uncore) can enter a low-power state.

A core in a sleep state (because of executing `hlt` or `mwait`) transitions to C0 (the active state) when any of the following events occur:

- An interrupt occurs (it doesn't have to be affine to the core).
- An address monitored by the core (by executing `monitor` on a valid WB address range) is stored to.
- The timer expires in case of a timed `mwait`.

You can find this information documented in the datasheets of Intel processors. Of course, there is shitload of errata related to `mwait` and `monitor`.

## Summary

```
╔══╦═════════════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║  ║                                     ║ mwait                 ║ mwaitx         ║ umwait          ║ pause          ║ tpause          ║ hlt              ║
╠══╩═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Wakeup triggers:                       ║                       ║                ║                 ║                ║                 ║                  ║
╠══╦═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ WB store from a processor agent     ║ +                     ║ +              ║ +               ║ –              ║ –               ║ –                ║
╠══╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ WB store from a non-processor agent ║ No guarantee          ║ No guarantee   ║ +               ║ –              ║ –               ║ –                ║
╠══╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ Non-WB stores                       ║ No guarantee          ║ No guarantee   ║ No guarantee    ║ –              ║ –               ║ –                ║
╠══╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ Unmasked interrupt                  ║ +                     ║ +              ║ +               ║ ?              ║ +               ║ +                ║
╠══╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ Masked interrrupt                   ║ + (1)                 ║ + (1)          ║ + (1)           ║ ?              ║ +               ║ –                ║
╠══╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ Timer                               ║ – (2)                 ║ + (3)          ║ + (4)           ║ –              ║ + (4)           ║ –                ║
╠══╬═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║  ║ Implementation-dependent            ║ +                     ║ –              ║ +               ║ –              ║ +               ║ –                ║
╠══╩═════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ User mode                              ║ – (5)                 ║ +              ║ +               ║ +              ║ +               ║ –                ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Wakeup IP                              ║ Next                  ║ Next           ║ Next            ║ Next           ║ Next            ║ Next or same (6) ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Deepest C-state                        ║ Deepest supported (7) ║ C1             ║ C0.2 (8)        ║ C0 (9)         ║ C0.2 (8)        ║ C1               ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Doesn't abort transaction              ║ +                     ║ N/A            ║ +               ║ –              ║ +               ║ –                ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Real mode                              ║ –                     ║ –              ║ –               ║ –              ║ –               ║ +                ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Support                                ║ 90nm P4+              ║ AMD Excavator+ ║ Atom Tremont,   ║ 130nm P4+ (10) ║ Atom Tremont,   ║ All x86          ║
║                                        ║                       ║                ║ Alder Lake,     ║                ║ Alder Lake,     ║                  ║
║                                        ║                       ║                ║ Sapphire Rapids ║                ║ Sapphire Rapids ║                  ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

(This ASCII art was generated using [TablesGenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables).)

Notes:
(1) This behavior is configurable via the `ecx` parameter.
(2) It actually does support a timer, at least on recent micorarchitecturs. However, this feature is not documented.
(3) Wait time is stored in a 32-bit field, in contrast to `umwait` and `tpause` where it's stored in a 64-bit field.
(4) A maximum wait time may be specified in `IA32_UMWAIT_CONTROL`.
(5) On KNL and KNM, setting `MISC_FEATURE_ENABLES[1]` to 1 allows the instruction to be executed in user mode.
(6) The `hlt` instruction is re-executed following an SMI if auto halt restart is enabled.
(7) On KNL and KNM, if `MISC_FEATURE_ENABLES[1]` is 1, the deepest C-state is C1.
(8) IF `IA32_UMWAIT_CONTROL[0]` is 1, the deepest C-state is C0.1.
(9) According to my understanding.
(10) Behaves as `nop` on all 32-bit and 64-bit Intel and AMD processors that don't support it.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/hlt says CS:EIP points to the instruction *following* the HLT instruction, after an interrupt return.  That's why you either `cli`/`hlt` (and assume no NMI) or put `hlt` in a loop at the end of a toy bootloader, as an alternative to `jmp $`.

Comment: @PeterCordes [felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mwait) says that "Unlike the HLT instruction, the MWAIT instruction does not support a restart at the MWAIT instruction following the handling of an SMI." The same for UMWAIT. Maybe this is specific to SMIs?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, see Section 34.10 of Volume 3.

Comment: Yes, I assume that's about SMI, not regular interrupts.  I don't know enough about SMIs and SMM, or `mwait`, to draw any more conclusions.

Comment: Interesting update.  I wonder if `pause` has anything to "wake up" from.  I'd guess it doesn't delay interrupt handling.  It probably just sleeps the front-end for a fixed number of cycles, as well as having a special uop for the back-end or issue stage that prevents memory-order mis-speculation

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry I don't know whether `pause` delays interrupts. I couldn't find any discussion on this. But yes, `pause` doesn't actually put the core into a sleep state; it remains in C0. Other than that, it's exact behavior is implementation-dependent though and it's not really clear to me. I'll try find more information when I get the time. I think `tpause` also doesn't put the core into sleep; but we'll have to wait for Intel to release the Tremont datasheet for more info on C0.1 and C0.2.

Comment: I'd guess that `pause` doesn't delay interrupts, at least in SKL and later, otherwise they might not have increased its delay from ~5 to ~100 cycles.  But I'm not super interested in knowing; a store buffer full of cache-miss stores can already effectively delay interrupt handling significantly more than that under normal conditions.  Don't spend your time looking on my behalf, only if your own curiosity compels you :)

Answer (score 7):

> What are the semantics of these instructions?

The general idea is that instead of having a polling loop (e.g. "`while( *foo == 0) {}`") you set up the monitor (using `monitor`) then check the condition, then (if the condition hasn't happened) wait for the monitor to be triggered (using `mwait`). This allows the CPU to consume less power (and/or lets a different logical processor in the same core run better) while waiting for the condition to change.

However; there can be false positives (writes to something else in the same cache line) and other things (IRQs) that cause `mwait` to stop waiting. For that reason you still need to check the condition in a loop; so the whole thing ends up like (e.g.) "`monitor(foo); while(*foo == 0) { mwait(); }`.

> Is this integrated through linux into the threading libraries provided by posix (eg. does the thread yield while monitoring a word)?

These instructions typically can't be used in user-space (require CPL=0). Note: There was a proposed extension to allow (a version of) monitor/mwait to be used in user-space, but I'm not sure if it ever got implemented (yet?).

However; they are often used in the kernel's scheduler when there's no tasks that want the CPU (to monitor an empty list of tasks that want the CPU and wake the CPU up when a task gets added to the list). In that way, it could end up being used by higher-level user-space things (e.g. pthread_condvars).

Note: Ages ago (maybe about 5 years?) I remember seeing some research into using `monitor`/`mwait` for spinlocks (in kernel); where the conclusion was that it took too long for the CPU to wake up and wasn't worth doing. I'm not sure if anything has changed since.

> Or are these just fancier versions of the pause instruction?

The `pause` instruction is very different - it tells the CPU not to aggressively (speculatively) execute future instruction (and don't tell the CPU to wait/execute no instructions). It's also useful in polling loops, but for different reasons.

> Consequently, what is the relation of these instructions on hyperthreading?

If one logical CPU in a core is doing nothing (e.g. `mwait`, `hlt`) then the other logical CPU in the core can use the whole core to execute stuff faster.

If one logical CPU in a core is doing less (because `pause` told the CPU not to be so aggressive with speculative execution) then the other logical CPU in the core can use more of the core to execute stuff little faster.

Comment: User-space `umonitor`/[`umwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) is coming in Tremont (atom), in the "WAITPKG" CPU feature.  Along with [`tpause`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/tpause) to `pause` until a TSC deadline.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks (I didn't remember the specifics). I hope there's a way for kernel to disable these instructions when they arrive - I can see potential security disasters (especially for 1st implementation, where there's a higher than average risk of "teething trouble"). ;-)

Comment: AFAIK, `mwait` is the only way to put the CPU in a deep sleep (C-states).  So that's the other huge benefit to using it in the scheduler when there's nothing to do.

Comment: Interesting point about security,  From the Intel manual, it looks like they only fault (in user-space) if the CR4.TSD bit is set (timestamp disable I think). 
 So unless there's something else documented elsewhere for disabling the feature, we're stuck with waiting for microcode updates if anything turns out badly.  The deepest sleep `umwait` or `tpause` can request is nowher near as deep as `mwait` so they anticipated the DOS / breaking real-time concern. 
 (also, https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-V3-Intel-UMWAIT has some fluff news and links on Linux prep for it)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Heh - after meltdown and spectre I'd be anticipating "attacker umwaits on victims write" scenarios (e.g. maybe as yet another way to break address layout randomization schemes).

Comment: That would probably only get you physical addresses and not help much, unless there's some aliasing thing that lets you discover some address bits...  But I notice they're rolling this out in Tremont first; most of those are client devices, not hosting VMs that don't trust each other.  And many Atom-powered devices are NASes whose threat model probably trusts all the code running on the device, outside of privilege escalation.

Comment: Update, Hadi's answer points out the `IA32_UMWAIT_CONTROL` MSR that lets the kernel control what user-space can do with it.  (Described by the [`umwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) manual entry). It has 1 reserved bit, so if a bug is discovered they'll probably release a ucode update that uses that reserved bit, or adds another MSR. But without a ucode update all you can do is disallow C0.2 state and set a very very short limit on the max time allowed in C0.1 state.  min encodeable = 4 TSC ticks. But spinning on that might still see an occasional CF=0 wake-from-activity not time