# Does UMWAIT make the process do REP NOP or context switch immediately?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, synchronization, locking

Does calling UMWAIT make the process to do REP NOP (= keep using its hardware thread, not evicted, but use less power by not issuing the uOPs to the processor backend) until its scheduled time is over?
Or, does it make the process to be evicted right away through context switch?

Comment: MWAIT is not available on userland (except on Xeon-Phi which are almost not used anymore and this require some tuning anyway). Are you working on the kernel? Note you can get many information about MWAIT [in this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471862/uses-of-the-monitor-mwait-instructions).

Comment: MWAIT doesn't cause a context switch. But it also doesn't keep executing instructions or uops. It puts the cpu into a low power state where it is more or less asleep waiting for an event to wake it up.

Comment: Yes, [`umwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) (the user-mode version of `mwait` with a limit on how deep a sleep it can do) is basically like `pause` (`rep nop`).  It doesn't make a yield() system-call or otherwise trap to the OS.  Same for `mwait` in kernel mode; it sleeps the CPU core, not traps.  If it just trapped so the OS could context switch, it wouldn't need to exist.  `int` or `syscall` instructions already exist.  Or in a kernel, a simple `call schedule` would potentially context-switch.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! I forgot to mention as Usermode UMWAIT instead of MWAIT. BTW, does REP NOP (PAUSE) and UMWAIT allow the other SMT thread on the same core to use core backend? Or, do these instructions also block other SMT thread on the same core?

Comment: The back-end is already competitively shared (except a few things like the ROB being statically partitioned).  Pausing the front-end for this logical thread lets the other logical thread have all the front-end cycles, just like if it stalled to recover from a branch mispredict.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much for your answer! Can I ask you one more? On the Intel x86 manual, UMWAIT will put the core into C0.2/C0.1 state to save power. But is there any meaning? Well, if the other SMT thread is active, most of backend/frontend will be active to C0.0, and if the other SMT thread is not active, then it will probably go into C1~ state.

Comment: Yeah, if the other logical core is still active, the core should keep running.  I don't know the details on what sleep levels real microarchitectures actually have in practice, and how the on-paper levels of sleep map to them.  It might be a more shallow sleep if regular C1 doesn't have a low enough wake-up latency, since some OSes would definitely want to stop user-space from doing anything too high latency to meet realtime guarantees it wants to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [`umwait`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/umwait) (the user-mode version of `mwait` with a limit on how deep a sleep it can do) is basically like `pause` (encoded as `rep nop`, which is how it executes on ancient CPUs that don't recognize it as a `pause` instruction).

It doesn't make a `yield()` system-call or otherwise trap to the OS. Same for `mwait` in kernel mode; it sleeps the CPU core, not traps.  Kernels use it to put the CPU into a C-state until the next interrupt.  (I think it was originally designed for actually waiting for memory writes from another core, but now one of the primary purposes is an API that includes a sleep level, unlike `hlt`, so it's how CPUs expose deep sleep levels.  The waiting for memory use-case is still supported, too.)

If it just trapped so the OS could context switch, it wouldn't need to exist. `int` or `syscall` instructions already exist. Or in a kernel, a simple `call schedule` would potentially context-switch.

---

> UMWAIT will put the core into C0.2/C0.1 state to save power. ... if the other SMT thread is active, most of backend/frontend will be active to C0.0, and if the other SMT thread is not active, then it will probably go into C1~ state.

Yeah, if the other logical core is still active, the physical core should keep running.  (And maybe switch back to "single-threaded" mode, allowing the other logical core to use the full ROB and store buffer, and similarly un-partitioning any other statically-partitioned resources.  Check `perf stat -e cpu_clk_unhalted.one_thread_active` against the case where the other thread is fully idle.)

I don't know the details on what sleep levels real microarchitectures actually have in practice, and how the on-paper levels of sleep map to them. It might be a more shallow sleep if regular C1 doesn't have a low enough wake-up latency, since some OSes would definitely want to stop user-space from doing anything too high latency to meet realtime guarantees it wants to provide.