# C++ compiled code using 100% CPU

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have the following code (it gets all processes then search for a regex pattern in them, code for a larger personal project for malware detection), the code does what I want but the only problem it is using 100% of CPU, what do I do wrong? Bad memory allocation? I compiled it with MS Visual Studio 2010 (cl.exe /EHsc mycode.cpp)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib") 

void PrintProcessNameAndID(DWORD);
void find_locs(HANDLE process);
void ListProcesses();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ListProcesses();
}

void find_locs(HANDLE process) {

    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION info;

    for ( p = NULL;
        VirtualQueryEx(process, p, &info, sizeof(info)) == sizeof(info);
        p += info.RegionSize )
    {
        std::string buffer;

        if (info.State == MEM_COMMIT &&
            (info.Type == MEM_MAPPED || info.Type == MEM_PRIVATE))
        {
            DWORD bytes_read;

            buffer.resize(info.RegionSize);
            ReadProcessMemory(process, p, &buffer[0], info.RegionSize, &bytes_read);
            buffer.resize(bytes_read);

            const std::tr1::regex rx("([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})");
            std::tr1::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> res; 
            std::tr1::regex_search(buffer, res, rx);

            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open ("proc.txt", ios::app);

            for (unsigned int i=0; i<res.size(); ++i)
            {
                std::cout << res[i] << std::endl;
                myfile << res[i] << "\n";
            }

            myfile.close();
        }
    }
}

void ListProcesses()
{
    DWORD aProcesses[1024];
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    DWORD cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses,sizeof(aProcesses),&cbNeeded))
        return;

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        PrintProcessNameAndID(aProcesses[i]);
    }
}

void PrintProcessNameAndID(DWORD processID)
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH]; // = TEXT("<unknown>");

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID);

    if (NULL != hProcess)
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
             &cbNeeded))
        {
            GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                               sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR));
        }
    }
    _tprintf(TEXT("pid: %u file: %s\n"), processID, szProcessName);
    find_locs(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Put in some sleep calls ;)

Comment: If it's causing a real problem, like slowing down other processes too much, rather than just a perceived one you could also look at dropping the thread priority.

Comment: Yes, PeterJ, is what I mean, I don't want other programs running to be slowed down too much. How can I drop the thread priority. I don't need multi-threading, just one thread, is ok.

Comment: Seems compiler options make big difference...I compiled now with "cl.exe /EHsc /O2 mycode.cpp" and CPU is 100% less of the time and fluctuates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with a program taking up 100% of the processor... (I don't know how I can expand this answer beyond this)

Comment: You could add that it can even be more than 100% using multiple threads, and that's cool too!

Comment: You can expand by explaining the difference between I/O bound programs and CPU bound programs.

Answer (score 3):

Any program running continuosly without a `Sleep` call (some sort of saying to OS "I'm done for now") will try to run as fast as possible, requesting next iteration of the loop just after the previous one. It takes every available CPU cycle, because you've requested it to do so.

Comment: So should I add some sleeps?

Comment: If you don't need realtime response, well, yes. Try `Sleep(0)` first.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with some sleep(0). Same with Sleep(0)

Comment: And same without writing to file. I think I have to live with it, or maybe find a way to read only a minidump of the process memory...

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

The CPU running at 100% is not too uncommon. This is especially true if you are running computationally intensive tasks (such as prime number computations). Eg:

[How to get 100% CPU usage from a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244481/how-to-get-100-cpu-usage-from-a-c-program)

Or, what is probably more applicable in your case, is that it's due to a myriad combination of things related to windows itself, your hardware combination and configuration:

http://www.techradar.com/us/news/computing/why-is-my-cpu-running-at-100-710254

In all, it's not something to be too worried about. *Generally*, that is.