# Multiply two vectors of 32bit integers, producing a vector of 32bit result elements

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics, avx, avx2

What is the best way to multiply each 32bit entry of two `_mm256i` registers with each other?

`_mm256_mul_epu32` is not what I'm looking for because it produces 64bit outputs.  I want a 32bit result for every 32bit input element.

Moreover, I'm sure that the multiplication of two 32bit values will not overflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fastest way to multiply two vectors in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264399/fastest-way-to-multiply-two-vectors-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `_mm256_mullo_epi32()` intrinsic. From Intel's excellent [online intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/):

> ## Synopsis
>
> ```
> __m256i _mm256_mullo_epi32 (__m256i a, __m256i b)
> #include "immintrin.h" 
> Instruction: vpmulld ymm, ymm, ymm CPUID Flags: AVX2
> ```
>
> ## Description
>
> Multiply the packed 32-bit integers in a and b,
>   producing intermediate 64-bit integers, and store the low 32 bits of
>   the intermediate integers in dst.

Comment: Do you happen to know the AVX equivalent?

Comment: @Bram There isn't one. AVX doesn't have integer instructions; they were added in AVX2. You'll have to use the SSE equivalents.