# Efficient 4x4 matrix multiplication (C vs assembly)

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, sse, matrix-multiplication

I'm looking for a faster and trickier way to multiply two 4x4 matrices in C. My current research is focused on x86-64 assembly with SIMD extensions. So far, I've created a function witch is about 6x faster than a naive C implementation, which has exceeded my expectations for the performance improvement. Unfortunately, this stays true only when no optimization flags are used for compilation (GCC 4.7). With `-O2`, C becomes faster and my effort becomes meaningless.

I know that modern compilers make use of complex optimization techniques to achieve an almost perfect code, usually faster than an ingenious piece of hand-crafed assembly. But in a minority of performance-critical cases, a human may try to fight for clock cycles with the compiler. Especially, when some mathematics backed with a modern ISA can be explored (as it is in my case).

My function looks as follows (AT&T syntax, GNU Assembler):

```
    .text
    .globl matrixMultiplyASM
    .type matrixMultiplyASM, @function
matrixMultiplyASM:
    movaps   (%rdi), %xmm0    # fetch the first matrix (use four registers)
    movaps 16(%rdi), %xmm1
    movaps 32(%rdi), %xmm2
    movaps 48(%rdi), %xmm3
    xorq %rcx, %rcx           # reset (forward) loop iterator
.ROW:
    movss (%rsi), %xmm4       # Compute four values (one row) in parallel:
    shufps $0x0, %xmm4, %xmm4 # 4x 4FP mul's, 3x 4FP add's 6x mov's per row,
    mulps %xmm0, %xmm4        # expressed in four sequences of 5 instructions,
    movaps %xmm4, %xmm5       # executed 4 times for 1 matrix multiplication.
    addq $0x4, %rsi

    movss (%rsi), %xmm4       # movss + shufps comprise _mm_set1_ps intrinsic
    shufps $0x0, %xmm4, %xmm4 #
    mulps %xmm1, %xmm4
    addps %xmm4, %xmm5
    addq $0x4, %rsi           # manual pointer arithmetic simplifies addressing

    movss (%rsi), %xmm4
    shufps $0x0, %xmm4, %xmm4
    mulps %xmm2, %xmm4        # actual computation happens here
    addps %xmm4, %xmm5        #
    addq $0x4, %rsi

    movss (%rsi), %xmm4       # one mulps operand fetched per sequence
    shufps $0x0, %xmm4, %xmm4 #  |
    mulps %xmm3, %xmm4        # the other is already waiting in %xmm[0-3]
    addps %xmm4, %xmm5
    addq $0x4, %rsi           # 5 preceding comments stride among the 4 blocks

    movaps %xmm5, (%rdx,%rcx) # store the resulting row, actually, a column
    addq $0x10, %rcx          # (matrices are stored in column-major order)
    cmpq $0x40, %rcx
    jne .ROW
    ret
.size matrixMultiplyASM, .-matrixMultiplyASM
```

It calculates a whole column of the resultant matrix per iteration, by processing four floats packed in 128-bit SSE registers. The full vectorisation is possible with a bit of math (operation reordering and aggregation) and `mullps`/`addps` instructions for parallel multiplication/addition of 4xfloat packages. The code reuses registers meant for passing parameters (`%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx` : GNU/Linux ABI), benefits from (inner) loop unrolling and holds one matrix entirely in XMM registers to reduce memory reads. A you can see, I have researched the topic and took my time to implement it the best I can.

The naive C calculation conquering my code looks like this:

```
void matrixMultiplyNormal(mat4_t *mat_a, mat4_t *mat_b, mat4_t *mat_r) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 16; i += 4)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            mat_r->m[i + j] = (mat_b->m[i + 0] * mat_a->m[j +  0])
                            + (mat_b->m[i + 1] * mat_a->m[j +  4])
                            + (mat_b->m[i + 2] * mat_a->m[j +  8])
                            + (mat_b->m[i + 3] * mat_a->m[j + 12]);
}
```

I have investigated the optimised assembly output of the above's C code which, while storing floats in XMM registers, *does not involve any parallel operations* – just scalar calculations, pointer arithmetic and conditional jumps. The compiler's code seems to be less deliberate, but it is still slightly more effective than my vectorised version expected to be about 4x faster. I'm sure that the general idea is correct – programmers do similar things with rewarding results. But what is wrong here? Are there any register allocation or instruction scheduling issues I am not aware of? Do you know any x86-64 assembly tools or tricks to support my battle against the machine?

Comment: Recent compilers can micro-optimize better than humans. Focus on algorithmic optimization!

Comment: This is exactly what I've done -- I used an alternative calculation to adapt the problem for SSE. It is actually a different algorithm. The problem is, probably, that now I also have to optimize it at the instruction level because, while focusing on the algorithm, I might have introduced data dependency problems, ineffective memory access patterns or some other black magic.

Comment: You might be better off using SSE intrinsics available through `<immintrin.h>` - you can try other things like `_mm_dp_ps` with `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS`, without maintaining assembly.

Comment: If you add the `restrict` qualifier to the pointer arguments to the C function and compile with `-O3`, GCC will vectorise it.  Without the `restrict` qualifiers, the compiler has to assume that the output matrix could be the same as one of the input matrices.

Comment: @BrettHale, I agree intrinsics are the way to do this but `_mm_dp_ps` or `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS` will be inefficient. See my answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967969/efficient-4x4-matrix-vector-multiplication-with-sse-horizontal-add-and-dot-prod

Comment: I have also an implementation utilizing SSE intrinsics which gives only about 10% speedup with -O2, while being almost two times slower when optimization is disabled. Since it's so optimization-dependant, I decided to touch pure assembly to make the most of the SSE approach. Unfortunately, this led to the slowest solution. Maybe I should go back to intrinsics and experiment more in this area.

Comment: @KrzysztofAbramowicz, AVX has been out for quite a while now.  Have you considered doing this with AVX?  I can add some code showing how to get twice the speed as SSE for 4x4 matrix multiplication.  At least for multiplying an array of 4x4 matrices times a fixed one.

Comment: I found similar considerations in questions [how to achieve 4 FLOPs per cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389648/how-to-achieve-4-flops-per-cycle?lq=1) and [C code loop performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992054/c-code-loop-performance?lq=1).

Comment: how does "restrict" translates to other compilers ? (clang, msvc, icc)

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint, it is possible to [reduce this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662382) to 48 multiplications and 120 additions, which may be of interest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a way to accelerate the code and outplay the compiler. It does not involve any sophisticated pipeline analysis or deep code micro-optimisation (which doesn't mean that it couldn't further benefit from these). The optimisation uses three simple tricks:

1. The function is now 32-byte aligned (which significantly boosted performance),
2. Main loop goes inversely, which reduces comparison to a zero test (based on EFLAGS),
3. Instruction-level address arithmetic proved to be faster than the "external" pointer calculation (even though it requires twice as much additions «in 3/4 cases»). It shortened the loop body by four instructions and reduced data dependencies within its execution path. [See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552677/how-does-address-operand-affect-performance-and-size-of-machine-code).

Additionally, the code uses a relative jump syntax which suppresses symbol redefinition error, which occurs when GCC tries to inline it (after being placed within `asm` statement and compiled with `-O3`).

```
    .text
    .align 32                           # 1. function entry alignment
    .globl matrixMultiplyASM            #    (for a faster call)
    .type matrixMultiplyASM, @function
matrixMultiplyASM:
    movaps   (%rdi), %xmm0
    movaps 16(%rdi), %xmm1
    movaps 32(%rdi), %xmm2
    movaps 48(%rdi), %xmm3
    movq $48, %rcx                      # 2. loop reversal
1:                                      #    (for simpler exit condition)
    movss (%rsi, %rcx), %xmm4           # 3. extended address operands
    shufps $0, %xmm4, %xmm4             #    (faster than pointer calculation)
    mulps %xmm0, %xmm4
    movaps %xmm4, %xmm5
    movss 4(%rsi, %rcx), %xmm4
    shufps $0, %xmm4, %xmm4
    mulps %xmm1, %xmm4
    addps %xmm4, %xmm5
    movss 8(%rsi, %rcx), %xmm4
    shufps $0, %xmm4, %xmm4
    mulps %xmm2, %xmm4
    addps %xmm4, %xmm5
    movss 12(%rsi, %rcx), %xmm4
    shufps $0, %xmm4, %xmm4
    mulps %xmm3, %xmm4
    addps %xmm4, %xmm5
    movaps %xmm5, (%rdx, %rcx)
    subq $16, %rcx                      # one 'sub' (vs 'add' & 'cmp')
    jge 1b                              # SF=OF, idiom: jump if positive
    ret
```

This is the fastest x86-64 implementation I have seen so far. I will appreciate, vote up and accept any answer providing a faster piece of assembly for that purpose!

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm calling it from C with this signature:
    void abramowicz_MM4x4(float *A, float *B, float *C);
And then I have the assembly in another file named to match gcc name mangling:
        .globl __Z16abramowicz_MM4x4PfS_S_
    __Z16abramowicz_MM4x4PfS_S_:
The call gives incorrect values. What might be going wrong?

Comment: The issue was that the order of the arguments are flipped. For anyone who is going to try this either flip A and B in the function signature in C or flip rdi and rsi in the asm.

Comment: anyone have an intel ASM translation of above?

Comment: I wrote an extended blog post on the subject located [here](http://nfrechette.github.io/2017/04/13/modern_simd_matrix_multiplication/). I also translated the assembly version into something usable by Visual Studio although some minor changes were made to my version to keep it binary exact. My non-assembly version is a bit faster though!

Answer (score 39):

4x4 matrix multiplication is 64 multiplications and 48 additions.  Using SSE this can be reduced to 16 multiplications and 12 additions (and 16 broadcasts).  The following code will do this for you.  It only requires SSE (`#include <xmmintrin.h>`).  The arrays `A`, `B`, and `C` need to be 16 byte aligned.  Using horizontal instructions such as `hadd` (SSE3) and `dpps` (SSE4.1) will be [less efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967969/efficient-4x4-matrix-vector-multiplication-with-sse-horizontal-add-and-dot-prod) (especially `dpps`).  I don't know if loop unrolling will help.

```
void M4x4_SSE(float *A, float *B, float *C) {
    __m128 row1 = _mm_load_ps(&B[0]);
    __m128 row2 = _mm_load_ps(&B[4]);
    __m128 row3 = _mm_load_ps(&B[8]);
    __m128 row4 = _mm_load_ps(&B[12]);
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        __m128 brod1 = _mm_set1_ps(A[4*i + 0]);
        __m128 brod2 = _mm_set1_ps(A[4*i + 1]);
        __m128 brod3 = _mm_set1_ps(A[4*i + 2]);
        __m128 brod4 = _mm_set1_ps(A[4*i + 3]);
        __m128 row = _mm_add_ps(
                    _mm_add_ps(
                        _mm_mul_ps(brod1, row1),
                        _mm_mul_ps(brod2, row2)),
                    _mm_add_ps(
                        _mm_mul_ps(brod3, row3),
                        _mm_mul_ps(brod4, row4)));
        _mm_store_ps(&C[4*i], row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The code looks better than my previous experiment with SSE intrinsics for matrix multiplication. It also gives a better-looking assembly with `-O2` and runs a bit faster than mine. But I am still wondering why I cannot achieve at least same results with pure assembly.

Comment: If you're using GCC why are you not compiling with `-O3`?

Comment: Maybe because I've always been told that `-O3` introduces aggressive optimisation techniques which may not boost performance, but may introduce additional cost, e.g. by increasing code size when unrolling loops or inlining functions. But you're right – first `-O3`, then low-level optimisation! :-) Fortunately, in my example it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 5):

Sandy Bridge an above extend the instruction set to support 8 element vector arithmetic. Consider this implementation.

```
struct MATRIX {
    union {
        float  f[4][4];
        __m128 m[4];
        __m256 n[2];
    };
};
MATRIX myMultiply(MATRIX M1, MATRIX M2) {
    // Perform a 4x4 matrix multiply by a 4x4 matrix 
    // Be sure to run in 64 bit mode and set right flags
    // Properties, C/C++, Enable Enhanced Instruction, /arch:AVX 
    // Having MATRIX on a 32 byte bundry does help performance
    MATRIX mResult;
    __m256 a0, a1, b0, b1;
    __m256 c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
    __m256 t0, t1, u0, u1;

    t0 = M1.n[0];                                                   // t0 = a00, a01, a02, a03, a10, a11, a12, a13
    t1 = M1.n[1];                                                   // t1 = a20, a21, a22, a23, a30, a31, a32, a33
    u0 = M2.n[0];                                                   // u0 = b00, b01, b02, b03, b10, b11, b12, b13
    u1 = M2.n[1];                                                   // u1 = b20, b21, b22, b23, b30, b31, b32, b33

    a0 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t0, t0, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0));        // a0 = a00, a00, a00, a00, a10, a10, a10, a10
    a1 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t1, t1, _MM_SHUFFLE(0, 0, 0, 0));        // a1 = a20, a20, a20, a20, a30, a30, a30, a30
    b0 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u0, u0, 0x00);                      // b0 = b00, b01, b02, b03, b00, b01, b02, b03  
    c0 = _mm256_mul_ps(a0, b0);                                     // c0 = a00*b00  a00*b01  a00*b02  a00*b03  a10*b00  a10*b01  a10*b02  a10*b03
    c1 = _mm256_mul_ps(a1, b0);                                     // c1 = a20*b00  a20*b01  a20*b02  a20*b03  a30*b00  a30*b01  a30*b02  a30*b03

    a0 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t0, t0, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1));        // a0 = a01, a01, a01, a01, a11, a11, a11, a11
    a1 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t1, t1, _MM_SHUFFLE(1, 1, 1, 1));        // a1 = a21, a21, a21, a21, a31, a31, a31, a31
    b0 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u0, u0, 0x11);                      // b0 = b10, b11, b12, b13, b10, b11, b12, b13
    c2 = _mm256_mul_ps(a0, b0);                                     // c2 = a01*b10  a01*b11  a01*b12  a01*b13  a11*b10  a11*b11  a11*b12  a11*b13
    c3 = _mm256_mul_ps(a1, b0);                                     // c3 = a21*b10  a21*b11  a21*b12  a21*b13  a31*b10  a31*b11  a31*b12  a31*b13

    a0 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t0, t0, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2));        // a0 = a02, a02, a02, a02, a12, a12, a12, a12
    a1 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t1, t1, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 2, 2, 2));        // a1 = a22, a22, a22, a22, a32, a32, a32, a32
    b1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u1, u1, 0x00);                      // b0 = b20, b21, b22, b23, b20, b21, b22, b23
    c4 = _mm256_mul_ps(a0, b1);                                     // c4 = a02*b20  a02*b21  a02*b22  a02*b23  a12*b20  a12*b21  a12*b22  a12*b23
    c5 = _mm256_mul_ps(a1, b1);                                     // c5 = a22*b20  a22*b21  a22*b22  a22*b23  a32*b20  a32*b21  a32*b22  a32*b23

    a0 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t0, t0, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3));        // a0 = a03, a03, a03, a03, a13, a13, a13, a13
    a1 = _mm256_shuffle_ps(t1, t1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 3, 3));        // a1 = a23, a23, a23, a23, a33, a33, a33, a33
    b1 = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(u1, u1, 0x11);                      // b0 = b30, b31, b32, b33, b30, b31, b32, b33
    c6 = _mm256_mul_ps(a0, b1);                                     // c6 = a03*b30  a03*b31  a03*b32  a03*b33  a13*b30  a13*b31  a13*b32  a13*b33
    c7 = _mm256_mul_ps(a1, b1);                                     // c7 = a23*b30  a23*b31  a23*b32  a23*b33  a33*b30  a33*b31  a33*b32  a33*b33

    c0 = _mm256_add_ps(c0, c2);                                     // c0 = c0 + c2 (two terms, first two rows)
    c4 = _mm256_add_ps(c4, c6);                                     // c4 = c4 + c6 (the other two terms, first two rows)
    c1 = _mm256_add_ps(c1, c3);                                     // c1 = c1 + c3 (two terms, second two rows)
    c5 = _mm256_add_ps(c5, c7);                                     // c5 = c5 + c7 (the other two terms, second two rose)

                                                                    // Finally complete addition of all four terms and return the results
    mResult.n[0] = _mm256_add_ps(c0, c4);       // n0 = a00*b00+a01*b10+a02*b20+a03*b30  a00*b01+a01*b11+a02*b21+a03*b31  a00*b02+a01*b12+a02*b22+a03*b32  a00*b03+a01*b13+a02*b23+a03*b33
                                                //      a10*b00+a11*b10+a12*b20+a13*b30  a10*b01+a11*b11+a12*b21+a13*b31  a10*b02+a11*b12+a12*b22+a13*b32  a10*b03+a11*b13+a12*b23+a13*b33
    mResult.n[1] = _mm256_add_ps(c1, c5);       // n1 = a20*b00+a21*b10+a22*b20+a23*b30  a20*b01+a21*b11+a22*b21+a23*b31  a20*b02+a21*b12+a22*b22+a23*b32  a20*b03+a21*b13+a22*b23+a23*b33
                                                //      a30*b00+a31*b10+a32*b20+a33*b30  a30*b01+a31*b11+a32*b21+a33*b31  a30*b02+a31*b12+a32*b22+a33*b32  a30*b03+a31*b13+a32*b23+a33*b33
    return mResult;
}
```

Comment: `.xmm[]` and `.ymm[]` might be better union member names.  Other than that, looks good.  Quite a lot of shuffling, though.  Might be worth storing to memory so you can broadcast-load.  (Unless the compiler "optimizes" it back into shuffles...)

Comment: On Haswell and later, `vbroadcastss ymm, [mem]` is a single uop in the load port.  On SnB/IvB, it's a load + port5 shuffle.  But that still beats 2 port5 shuffles for vshufps + vperm2f128.  (Or vinsertf128.)

Comment: Oh NVM, you're doing two separate in-lane broadcasts and the `permute2f128` is on the other operand.  Yeah, that looks good.  With `-march=haswell`, 4 of the mul/add pairs fold into FMAs:  https://godbolt.org/g/9uEbhR.  Hmm, those `_mm256_permute2f128_ps(same,same, 0)` are broadcasts, but compilers aren't turning them into `vinsertf128`.  This is where you could maybe save shuffle-port uops with broadcast-128 loads for Haswell.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if transposing one of the matrices may be beneficial.

Consider how we multiply the following two matrices ...

```
A1 A2 A3 A4        W1 W2 W3 W4
B1 B2 B3 B4        X1 X2 X3 X4
C1 C2 C3 C4    *   Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4
D1 D2 D3 D4        Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
```

This would result in ...

```
dot(A,?1) dot(A,?2) dot(A,?3) dot(A,?4)
dot(B,?1) dot(B,?2) dot(B,?3) dot(B,?4)
dot(C,?1) dot(C,?2) dot(C,?3) dot(C,?4)
dot(D,?1) dot(D,?2) dot(D,?3) dot(D,?4)
```

Doing the dot product of a row and a column is a pain.

What if we transposed the second matrix before we multiplied?

```
A1 A2 A3 A4        W1 X1 Y1 Z1
B1 B2 B3 B4        W2 X2 Y2 Z2
C1 C2 C3 C4    *   W3 X3 Y3 Z3
D1 D2 D3 D4        W4 X4 Y4 Z4
```

Now instead doing the dot product of a row and column, we are doing the dot product of two rows.  This could lend itself to better use of the SIMD instructions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You almost never want to do a dot product of two vectors with SSE.  Instead you do do four dot products at once.  You do the same thing you do with scalar code but instead you use SIMD registers.  E.g. for four components vectors this means you do 4 `_mm_mul_ps` and 3 `_mm_add_ps` and this gives you four dot products.

Comment: @redrum: I see.  Until now, I've been using combinations of "mulps" and "haddps" for dot products and matrix,vector multiplication.  Looks like I have some more tweaking to do.

Comment: `hadd` has its use sometimes but not in this case. I have never found `dpps` to be useful.

Comment: @Zboson Would you mind explaining your statement a bit further please? Why would you do 4 `_mm_mul_ps`s instead of `_mm_mul_ss`s, if everything is the same as in the scalar case?

Comment: @user1095108, I mean the SIMD code if used efficiently looks almost the same as the scalar case. Consider the 3D dot product `w = x1x2 + y1y2 +z1z1`. The variables here can be scalars or SIMD vectors and the results `w` is either a single number or the result of multiple dot products at once. Each case uses the same number of instructions: 3 mults and 2 adds. But the scalar case uses scalar instructions and the SIMD case the SIMD instructions.

Comment: @Zboson I've implemented your trick and it works very well. If you do need a single dot product, not a matrix multiplication row, you'd use _mm_dp_ps or _mm_hadd_ps?

Comment: @user1095108, I have never used `_mm_dp_ps` or `_mm_hadd_ps` for a single dot product. I would try to reorganize my code so that I don't have to. Read this http://www.cdl.uni-saarland.de/papers/leissa_vecimp_tr.pdf. But Intel must have created `_mm_dp_ps` for a reason. I read a note on this by them a while back. If you can't change your code and have to calculate one dot product at a time then `_mm_dp_ps` probably has some benefit but from what I recall it was a small improvement and nothing close to the factor of 4 you can get from doing four at once. You could write code to test this.

Comment: @Zboson You are right, of course, if you do need 4 at a time or can reorganize your code. It may be, that you don't/can't.

Comment: @user1095108, this may be of interest to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967969/efficient-4x4-matrix-vector-multiplication-with-sse-horizontal-add-and-dot-prod. It was my first post on SO.

Answer (score -3):

Obviously you can fetch terms from four matrices at a time and multiply four matrices simultaneously using the same algorithm.

Comment: Elaborate... does it really answer the question?

Comment: I don't think doing a gather of elements from four different input matrices and then a scatter back to four different result matrices would be faster than using load+broadcast like the OP's own answer does.