# Efficient SSE NxN matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, matrix-multiplication, simd

I'm trying to implement `SSE` version of large matrix by matrix multiplication.
 I'm looking for an efficient algorithm based on `SIMD` implementations.

My desired method looks like:

```
A(n x m) * B(m x k) = C(n x k)
```

And all matrices are considered to be 16-byte aligned float array.

I searched the net and found some articles describing 8x8 multiplication and even smaller. I really need it as efficient as possible and I don't want to use `Eigen` library or similar libraries. (Only `SSE3` to be more specific).

So I'd appreciate if anyone can help me find some articles or resources on how to start implementing this.

Comment: Using an established library is probably by far the easiest and bang/buck-effective way. What's the problem with that?

Comment: I finally want to implement it on device. I'd prefer it to be independent of third party libs

Comment: Do you need single-threaded or multi-threaded version?

Comment: I'm looking for single thread. with `SIMD` registers

Comment: What is the data type ? `float`, `double` or something else ? (This makes a big difference when it comes to SIMD implementations.)

Comment: @PaulR you are right. My matrices are of type `float`.

Comment: How about look at the source of a BLAS implementation and see what they do? These codes have lots of optimizations. ATLAS (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) is BSD-licensed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient 4x4 matrix multiplication (C vs assembly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499971/efficient-4x4-matrix-multiplication-c-vs-assembly)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main challenge in implementation of arbitrary-size matrix-matrix multiplication is not the use of SIMD, but reuse of cached data. The paper [Anatomy of High-Performance Matrix Multiplication by Goto and Van de Geijn](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/pingali/CS378/2008sp/papers/gotoPaper.pdf) is a must-read if you want to implement cache-friendly matrix-matrix multiplication, and it also discusses the choice of kernels to be SIMD-friendly. After reading this paper expect to achieve 50% of machine peak on matrix-matrix multiplication after two weeks of efforts.

However, if the purpose of this work is not pure learning, I strongly recommend to use a highly optimized library. On x86 your best options are [OpenBLAS](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS) (BSD-licensed, supports dynamic CPU dispatching), [BLIS](https://github.com/flame/blis) (BSD-licensed, easily portable to new processors), and [Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) (commercial, supports dynamic CPU dispatching on Intel processors). For performance reasons it is better to avoid ATLAS unless you target a very exotic architecture which is not supported by other libraries.

Comment: Thanks for a very useful article you provided

Comment: Good paper Marat.  It took me much longer than two weeks to break 50% (using multiple threads as well) but I did not have that paper.  I now get over 70% with AVX on Ivy Bridge and 55% with FMA3 on Haswell (still better than 100% compared to Ivy Bridge).

Comment: @Zboson I also recommend to look at the papers on BLIS, especially if you are interested in multi-core optimizations for linear algebra. They are here: https://code.google.com/p/blis/#Citations