# Understanding 4K aliasing on Intel CPU's

Tags: performance, x86, intel, cpu-architecture

I've been reading about 4K aliasing caused by load/store overlaps due to ambiguity in address bits 6 to 11 on Intel CPU's.  So I am trying to write various simple tests (on a i7-3770k, Win7, 64bit, VS2017) to specifically cause the issue to make sure I understand it in practice.

The first test I have been trying but failed to make exhibit the behaviour is:

```c
void Test4KAliasing1()
{
    typedef float Value;// Also tried with double


    const uint32_t ValueCount = 1024;
    const uint32_t OffsetCount = 256;
    const uint32_t TestCount = 512;


    Value* a = (Value*)_aligned_malloc(ValueCount * sizeof(Value), 4096);
    Value* b = (Value*)_aligned_malloc(ValueCount * sizeof(Value), 4096);


    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ValueCount; ++i)
        a[i] = b[i] = (Value)rand();

    for (uint32_t offset = 0; offset < OffsetCount; ++offset)
    {
        uint64_t startTime = StartCPUCycles();


        for (uint32_t test = 0; test < TestCount; ++test)
        {
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ValueCount; ++i)
            {
                uint32_t j = (offset + i) % ValueCount;


                a[i] += b[j] * 3.142f;
            }
        }


        uint64_t duration = EndCPUCycles() - startTime;


        printf("time: %llu\toffset: %u ", duration / TestCount, offset);
        printf("\n", a, b);
    }


    _aligned_free(b);
    _aligned_free(a);
}
```

Which was inspired by: http://richardstartin.uk/the-much-aligned-garbage-collector/

So I am not quite sure why this doesn't show the problem from the resulting timings?  As I would have thought stores then loads to/from ambiguous addresses would happen across the loop iterations due to out of order execution?

The assembly generated was:

```
000000013F2510E4  cpuid  
000000013F2510E6  rdtsc  
000000013F2510E8  shl         rdx,20h  
000000013F2510EC  mov         r9d,200h  
000000013F2510F2  or          rax,rdx  
000000013F2510F5  mov         r10,rax  
000000013F2510F8  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
000000013F251100  lea         ebx,[rsi+1]  
000000013F251103  mov         r8d,80h  
000000013F251109  lea         rdx,[r14+8]  
000000013F25110D  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
000000013F251110  mov         rax,rbx  
000000013F251113  lea         ecx,[rbx-1]  
000000013F251116  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F25111B  lea         rdx,[rdx+20h]  
000000013F25111F  and         ecx,3FFh  
000000013F251125  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rcx*4]  
000000013F25112A  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-28h]  
000000013F25112F  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-28h],xmm2  
000000013F251134  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F251139  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-24h]  
000000013F25113E  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-24h],xmm2  
000000013F251143  lea         eax,[rbx+1]  
000000013F251146  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F25114B  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F251150  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-20h]  
000000013F251155  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-20h],xmm2  
000000013F25115A  lea         eax,[rbx+2]  
000000013F25115D  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F251162  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F251167  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-1Ch]  
000000013F25116C  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-1Ch],xmm2  
000000013F251171  lea         eax,[rbx+3]  
000000013F251174  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F251179  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F25117E  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-18h]  
000000013F251183  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-18h],xmm2  
000000013F251188  lea         eax,[rbx+4]  
000000013F25118B  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F251190  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F251195  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-14h]  
000000013F25119A  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-14h],xmm2  
000000013F25119F  lea         eax,[rbx+5]  
000000013F2511A2  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F2511A7  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F2511AC  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-10h]  
000000013F2511B1  lea         eax,[rbx+6]  
000000013F2511B4  add         ebx,8  
000000013F2511B7  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-10h],xmm2  
000000013F2511BC  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F2511C1  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F2511C6  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-0Ch]  
000000013F2511CB  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-0Ch],xmm2  
000000013F2511D0  sub         r8,1  
000000013F2511D4  jne         Test4KAliasing1+0B0h (013F251110h)  
000000013F2511DA  sub         r9,1  
000000013F2511DE  jne         Test4KAliasing1+0A0h (013F251100h)  
000000013F2511E4  rdtsc
```

Also on the web I have seen various descriptions that say the bottom 12bits must match for this aliasing to occur, and in other places only bits 6 to 11?  As the lowest 6 bits are the bytes indices within a cache line and everything is cache line based anyway, then I would have thought it would only needs bits 6 to 11 to match?

EDIT:

Also as per Peters' answer I have tried:

```
a[i] *= 1.234f;
b[j] += 4.321f;
```

Which doesn't seem to show the problem and generates:

```
000000013F6C10E8  cpuid  
000000013F6C10EA  rdtsc  
000000013F6C10EC  shl         rdx,20h  
000000013F6C10F0  mov         ebx,200h  
000000013F6C10F5  or          rax,rdx  
000000013F6C10F8  mov         r9,rax  
000000013F6C10FB  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
000000013F6C1100  lea         edx,[rsi+1]  
000000013F6C1103  mov         r8d,80h  
000000013F6C1109  lea         rcx,[r14+8]  
000000013F6C110D  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
000000013F6C1110  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-8]  
000000013F6C1115  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-8],xmm1  
000000013F6C111A  lea         eax,[rdx-1]  
000000013F6C111D  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C1122  lea         rcx,[rcx+20h]  
000000013F6C1126  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C112B  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C1130  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-24h]  
000000013F6C1135  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-24h],xmm1  
000000013F6C113A  mov         rax,rdx  
000000013F6C113D  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C1142  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C1147  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C114C  vmulss      xmm0,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-20h]  
000000013F6C1151  lea         eax,[rdx+1]  
000000013F6C1154  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C1159  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-20h],xmm0  
000000013F6C115E  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C1163  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C1168  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-1Ch]  
000000013F6C116D  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-1Ch],xmm1  
000000013F6C1172  lea         eax,[rdx+2]  
000000013F6C1175  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C117A  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C117F  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C1184  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-18h]  
000000013F6C1189  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-18h],xmm1  
000000013F6C118E  lea         eax,[rdx+3]  
000000013F6C1191  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C1196  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C119B  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C11A0  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-14h]  
000000013F6C11A5  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-14h],xmm1  
000000013F6C11AA  lea         eax,[rdx+4]  
000000013F6C11AD  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C11B2  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C11B7  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C11BC  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-10h]  
000000013F6C11C1  lea         eax,[rdx+5]  
000000013F6C11C4  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C11C9  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-10h],xmm1  
000000013F6C11CE  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C11D3  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C11D8  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx-0Ch]  
000000013F6C11DD  lea         eax,[rdx+6]  
000000013F6C11E0  add         edx,8  
000000013F6C11E3  and         eax,3FFh  
000000013F6C11E8  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-0Ch],xmm1  
000000013F6C11ED  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F6C11F2  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rax*4],xmm1  
000000013F6C11F7  sub         r8,1  
000000013F6C11FB  jne         Test4KAliasing1+0B0h (013F6C1110h)  
000000013F6C1201  sub         rbx,1  
000000013F6C1205  jne         Test4KAliasing1+0A0h (013F6C1100h)  
000000013F6C120B  rdtsc
```

Also based on the linked question Peter mentioned I tried with 3 arrays:

```
a[i] += b[j] + c[j];
```

Which didn't appear to have the issue either.  The code generated was:

```
000000013F5110F6  cpuid  
000000013F5110F8  rdtsc  
000000013F5110FA  shl         rdx,20h  
000000013F5110FE  mov         r8d,200h  
000000013F511104  or          rax,rdx  
000000013F511107  mov         r10,rax  
000000013F51110A  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
000000013F511110  lea         ebx,[rbp+1]  
000000013F511113  mov         r9d,100h  
000000013F511119  lea         rdx,[r13+8]  
000000013F51111D  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
000000013F511120  mov         rax,rbx  
000000013F511123  lea         ecx,[rbx-1]  
000000013F511126  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F51112B  lea         rdx,[rdx+20h]  
000000013F51112F  and         ecx,7FFh  
000000013F511135  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rcx*4]  
000000013F51113A  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rcx*4]  
000000013F51113F  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-28h]  
000000013F511144  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-28h],xmm2  
000000013F511149  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F51114E  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F511153  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-24h]  
000000013F511158  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-24h],xmm2  
000000013F51115D  lea         eax,[rbx+1]  
000000013F511160  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F511165  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F51116A  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F51116F  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-20h]  
000000013F511174  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-20h],xmm2  
000000013F511179  lea         eax,[rbx+2]  
000000013F51117C  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F511181  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F511186  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F51118B  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-1Ch]  
000000013F511190  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-1Ch],xmm2  
000000013F511195  lea         eax,[rbx+3]  
000000013F511198  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F51119D  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111A2  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111A7  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-18h]  
000000013F5111AC  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-18h],xmm2  
000000013F5111B1  lea         eax,[rbx+4]  
000000013F5111B4  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F5111B9  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111BE  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111C3  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-14h]  
000000013F5111C8  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-14h],xmm2  
000000013F5111CD  lea         eax,[rbx+5]  
000000013F5111D0  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F5111D5  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111DA  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111DF  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-10h]  
000000013F5111E4  lea         eax,[rbx+6]  
000000013F5111E7  add         ebx,8  
000000013F5111EA  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-10h],xmm2  
000000013F5111EF  and         eax,7FFh  
000000013F5111F4  vmovss      xmm0,dword ptr [rsi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111F9  vaddss      xmm1,xmm0,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F5111FE  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-0Ch]  
000000013F511203  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-0Ch],xmm2  
000000013F511208  sub         r9,1  
000000013F51120C  jne         Test4KAliasing2+0C0h (013F511120h)  
000000013F511212  sub         r8,1  
000000013F511216  jne         Test4KAliasing2+0B0h (013F511110h)  
000000013F51121C  rdtsc
```

Further to Peter's comment/update on his answer I tried:

```
a[i] *= 1.234f;
b[i] += 4.321f;
```

Which didn't show the problem.  NOTE: I was trying to vary the offset of i with j = i + offset starting with a zero offset for most of these attempts previously to see what offset alleviate the problem if I could find it.  (I am still digging through the disassembly here to understand the address generation as my x86 is rusty).

```
000000013F7D1104  cpuid  
000000013F7D1106  rdtsc  
000000013F7D1108  shl         rdx,20h  
000000013F7D110C  or          rax,rdx  
000000013F7D110F  mov         edx,200h  
000000013F7D1114  mov         rbx,rax  
000000013F7D1117  cmp         rsi,r15  
000000013F7D111A  ja          Test4KAliasing1+130h (013F7D1190h)  
000000013F7D111C  cmp         rbp,r14  
000000013F7D111F  jb          Test4KAliasing1+130h (013F7D1190h)  
000000013F7D1121  lea         rcx,[rsi+4]  
000000013F7D1125  mov         eax,100h  
000000013F7D112A  nop         word ptr [rax+rax]  
000000013F7D1130  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rcx-4]  
000000013F7D1136  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rcx-4],xmm1  
000000013F7D113C  vaddss      xmm1,xmm7,dword ptr [rcx-4]  
000000013F7D1141  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx-4],xmm1  
000000013F7D1146  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rcx+rdi]  
000000013F7D114B  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+rdi],xmm1  
000000013F7D1150  vaddss      xmm0,xmm7,dword ptr [rcx]  
000000013F7D1154  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx],xmm0  
000000013F7D1158  vmulss      xmm0,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rcx+4]  
000000013F7D115E  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rcx+4],xmm0  
000000013F7D1164  vaddss      xmm0,xmm7,dword ptr [rcx+4]  
000000013F7D1169  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+4],xmm0  
000000013F7D116E  vmulss      xmm0,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rcx+8]  
000000013F7D1174  vmovss      dword ptr [rdi+rcx+8],xmm0  
000000013F7D117A  vaddss      xmm0,xmm7,dword ptr [rcx+8]  
000000013F7D117F  vmovss      dword ptr [rcx+8],xmm0  
000000013F7D1184  lea         rcx,[rcx+10h]  
000000013F7D1188  sub         rax,1  
000000013F7D118C  jne         Test4KAliasing1+0D0h (013F7D1130h)  
000000013F7D118E  jmp         Test4KAliasing1+1AEh (013F7D120Eh)  
000000013F7D1190  vmovups     xmm2,xmmword ptr [__xmm@3f9df3b63f9df3b63f9df3b63f9df3b6 (013F7EA0E0h)]  
000000013F7D1198  vmovups     xmm3,xmmword ptr [__xmm@408a45a2408a45a2408a45a2408a45a2 (013F7EA0F0h)]  
000000013F7D11A0  lea         rax,[rsi+10h]  
000000013F7D11A4  mov         ecx,40h  
000000013F7D11A9  nop         dword ptr [rax]  
000000013F7D11B0  vmulps      xmm1,xmm2,xmmword ptr [rdi+rax-10h]  
000000013F7D11B6  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rdi+rax-10h],xmm1  
000000013F7D11BC  vaddps      xmm1,xmm3,xmmword ptr [rax-10h]  
000000013F7D11C1  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rax-10h],xmm1  
000000013F7D11C6  vmulps      xmm1,xmm2,xmmword ptr [rdi+rax]  
000000013F7D11CB  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rdi+rax],xmm1  
000000013F7D11D0  vaddps      xmm1,xmm3,xmmword ptr [rax]  
000000013F7D11D4  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rax],xmm1  
000000013F7D11D8  vmulps      xmm1,xmm2,xmmword ptr [rdi+rax+10h]  
000000013F7D11DE  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rdi+rax+10h],xmm1  
000000013F7D11E4  vaddps      xmm1,xmm3,xmmword ptr [rax+10h]  
000000013F7D11E9  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rax+10h],xmm1  
000000013F7D11EE  vmulps      xmm1,xmm2,xmmword ptr [rdi+rax+20h]  
000000013F7D11F4  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rdi+rax+20h],xmm1  
000000013F7D11FA  vaddps      xmm1,xmm3,xmmword ptr [rax+20h]  
000000013F7D11FF  vmovups     xmmword ptr [rax+20h],xmm1  
000000013F7D1204  lea         rax,[rax+40h]  
000000013F7D1208  sub         rcx,1  
000000013F7D120C  jne         Test4KAliasing1+150h (013F7D11B0h)  
000000013F7D120E  sub         rdx,1  
000000013F7D1212  jne         Test4KAliasing1+0B7h (013F7D1117h)  
000000013F7D1218  rdtsc
```

A typical timing run for:

```
a[i] *= 1.234f;
b[i] += 4.321f;
```

is:

```
time: 715       offset: 0
time: 647       offset: 1
time: 641       offset: 2
time: 703       offset: 3
time: 658       offset: 4
time: 657       offset: 5
time: 656       offset: 6
time: 657       offset: 7
time: 658       offset: 8
time: 657       offset: 9
time: 658       offset: 10
time: 653       offset: 11
time: 658       offset: 12
time: 652       offset: 13
time: 658       offset: 14
time: 657       offset: 15
time: 658       offset: 16
time: 656       offset: 17
time: 659       offset: 18
time: 656       offset: 19
time: 656       offset: 20
time: 656       offset: 21
time: 663       offset: 22
time: 657       offset: 23
time: 657       offset: 24
time: 704       offset: 25
time: 714       offset: 26
time: 657       offset: 27
time: 658       offset: 28
time: 658       offset: 29
time: 656       offset: 30
time: 656       offset: 31
time: 657       offset: 32
time: 658       offset: 33
time: 658       offset: 34
time: 656       offset: 35
time: 658       offset: 36
time: 658       offset: 37
time: 658       offset: 38
time: 658       offset: 39
time: 660       offset: 40
time: 660       offset: 41
time: 664       offset: 42
time: 656       offset: 43
time: 656       offset: 44
time: 658       offset: 45
time: 656       offset: 46
time: 656       offset: 47
time: 713       offset: 48
time: 658       offset: 49
time: 663       offset: 50
time: 662       offset: 51
time: 665       offset: 52
time: 663       offset: 53
time: 665       offset: 54
time: 658       offset: 55
time: 658       offset: 56
time: 658       offset: 57
time: 656       offset: 58
time: 657       offset: 59
time: 658       offset: 60
time: 658       offset: 61
time: 656       offset: 62
time: 666       offset: 63
time: 656       offset: 64
time: 658       offset: 65
time: 656       offset: 66
time: 657       offset: 67
time: 658       offset: 68
time: 658       offset: 69
time: 652       offset: 70
time: 658       offset: 71
time: 657       offset: 72
time: 658       offset: 73
time: 658       offset: 74
time: 656       offset: 75
time: 658       offset: 76
time: 665       offset: 77
time: 657       offset: 78
time: 656       offset: 79
time: 656       offset: 80
time: 666       offset: 81
time: 656       offset: 82
time: 702       offset: 83
time: 640       offset: 84
time: 640       offset: 85
time: 657       offset: 86
time: 657       offset: 87
time: 658       offset: 88
time: 658       offset: 89
time: 656       offset: 90
time: 657       offset: 91
time: 657       offset: 92
time: 657       offset: 93
time: 658       offset: 94
time: 662       offset: 95
time: 658       offset: 96
time: 656       offset: 97
time: 657       offset: 98
time: 663       offset: 99
time: 660       offset: 100
time: 663       offset: 101
time: 657       offset: 102
time: 656       offset: 103
time: 664       offset: 104
time: 659       offset: 105
time: 659       offset: 106
time: 658       offset: 107
time: 774       offset: 108
time: 707       offset: 109
time: 710       offset: 110
time: 658       offset: 111
time: 657       offset: 112
time: 661       offset: 113
time: 658       offset: 114
time: 656       offset: 115
time: 658       offset: 116
time: 657       offset: 117
time: 658       offset: 118
time: 660       offset: 119
time: 666       offset: 120
time: 657       offset: 121
time: 658       offset: 122
time: 651       offset: 123
time: 658       offset: 124
time: 657       offset: 125
time: 657       offset: 126
time: 658       offset: 127
time: 656       offset: 128
time: 658       offset: 129
time: 656       offset: 130
time: 658       offset: 131
time: 645       offset: 132
time: 640       offset: 133
time: 640       offset: 134
time: 659       offset: 135
time: 664       offset: 136
time: 658       offset: 137
time: 662       offset: 138
time: 656       offset: 139
time: 658       offset: 140
time: 656       offset: 141
time: 658       offset: 142
time: 660       offset: 143
time: 658       offset: 144
time: 658       offset: 145
time: 656       offset: 146
time: 657       offset: 147
time: 664       offset: 148
time: 656       offset: 149
time: 656       offset: 150
time: 658       offset: 151
time: 656       offset: 152
time: 668       offset: 153
time: 656       offset: 154
time: 656       offset: 155
time: 656       offset: 156
time: 658       offset: 157
time: 656       offset: 158
time: 658       offset: 159
time: 660       offset: 160
time: 658       offset: 161
time: 658       offset: 162
time: 658       offset: 163
time: 658       offset: 164
time: 656       offset: 165
time: 686       offset: 166
time: 656       offset: 167
time: 656       offset: 168
time: 658       offset: 169
time: 656       offset: 170
time: 658       offset: 171
time: 656       offset: 172
time: 656       offset: 173
time: 656       offset: 174
time: 658       offset: 175
time: 656       offset: 176
time: 658       offset: 177
time: 658       offset: 178
time: 654       offset: 179
time: 639       offset: 180
time: 639       offset: 181
time: 639       offset: 182
time: 657       offset: 183
time: 641       offset: 184
time: 640       offset: 185
time: 640       offset: 186
time: 640       offset: 187
time: 640       offset: 188
time: 640       offset: 189
time: 640       offset: 190
time: 700       offset: 191
time: 715       offset: 192
time: 657       offset: 193
time: 657       offset: 194
time: 662       offset: 195
time: 703       offset: 196
time: 640       offset: 197
time: 639       offset: 198
time: 638       offset: 199
time: 640       offset: 200
time: 640       offset: 201
time: 640       offset: 202
time: 704       offset: 203
time: 638       offset: 204
time: 640       offset: 205
time: 639       offset: 206
time: 657       offset: 207
time: 658       offset: 208
time: 657       offset: 209
time: 659       offset: 210
time: 663       offset: 211
time: 658       offset: 212
time: 658       offset: 213
time: 657       offset: 214
time: 667       offset: 215
time: 657       offset: 216
time: 657       offset: 217
time: 658       offset: 218
time: 657       offset: 219
time: 656       offset: 220
time: 661       offset: 221
time: 651       offset: 222
time: 658       offset: 223
time: 658       offset: 224
time: 656       offset: 225
time: 658       offset: 226
time: 658       offset: 227
time: 672       offset: 228
time: 658       offset: 229
time: 656       offset: 230
time: 649       offset: 231
time: 665       offset: 232
time: 657       offset: 233
time: 652       offset: 234
time: 664       offset: 235
time: 656       offset: 236
time: 662       offset: 237
time: 658       offset: 238
time: 665       offset: 239
time: 658       offset: 240
time: 657       offset: 241
time: 656       offset: 242
time: 658       offset: 243
time: 657       offset: 244
time: 658       offset: 245
time: 658       offset: 246
time: 656       offset: 247
time: 658       offset: 248
time: 656       offset: 249
time: 658       offset: 250
time: 656       offset: 251
time: 665       offset: 252
time: 658       offset: 253
time: 656       offset: 254
time: 658       offset: 255
```

HOWEVER: I think I made a mistake and have now found it with:

```
a[i] *= 1.234f;
b[j] += 4.321f;
```

As a typical timing run is now:

```
time: 2794      offset: 0
time: 2737      offset: 1
time: 2655      offset: 2
time: 2748      offset: 3
time: 2605      offset: 4
time: 2730      offset: 5
time: 2665      offset: 6
time: 2703      offset: 7
time: 2571      offset: 8
time: 2558      offset: 9
time: 2213      offset: 10
time: 2200      offset: 11
time: 2325      offset: 12
time: 2200      offset: 13
time: 2200      offset: 14
time: 2264      offset: 15
time: 2264      offset: 16
time: 2355      offset: 17
time: 2348      offset: 18
time: 2262      offset: 19
time: 2260      offset: 20
time: 2262      offset: 21
time: 2260      offset: 22
time: 2490      offset: 23
time: 2261      offset: 24
time: 2260      offset: 25
time: 2255      offset: 26
time: 2261      offset: 27
time: 2263      offset: 28
time: 2260      offset: 29
time: 2260      offset: 30
time: 2262      offset: 31
time: 2264      offset: 32
time: 2355      offset: 33
time: 2266      offset: 34
time: 2270      offset: 35
time: 2260      offset: 36
time: 2268      offset: 37
time: 2260      offset: 38
time: 2260      offset: 39
time: 2262      offset: 40
time: 2260      offset: 41
time: 2259      offset: 42
time: 2260      offset: 43
time: 2260      offset: 44
time: 2255      offset: 45
time: 2260      offset: 46
time: 2265      offset: 47
time: 2263      offset: 48
time: 2355      offset: 49
time: 2293      offset: 50
time: 2204      offset: 51
time: 2323      offset: 52
time: 2200      offset: 53
time: 2200      offset: 54
time: 2460      offset: 55
time: 2200      offset: 56
```

Which is a ~20% difference as the offset gets larger that could be it?

Answer (score 4):

The bottom 12 bits are bits `[11 : 0]`.  Bit #11 is the 12th bit, because we count from 0.

CPUs detect load/store aliasing with byte granularity, not just whether a load accesses the same cache line as an older store.  Storing to `array[1]` doesn't slow down a load from `array[2]`; that would be really really bad for performance because looping through an array and RMWing each element one at a time is a very common pattern.   (Without software-pipelining to load several elements ahead of where we're storing.)

**So I think you're not hitting problems here because you're only storing to a location *after* loading from the same offset within a 4k page.**  If you did something like this simple loop (no extra striding or offset into another extra page is required, just two arrays in different pages is fine.)

```
for (i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++) {
    a[i] *= 1.234;
    b[i] += 4.321;    // load from the same offset we just wrote, but in another page
}
```

and the compiler made asm that stored to `a` before loading `b`, you'd have a problem since both `a` and `b` have the same alignment relative to a 4k page.

(A compiler could do both loads before either store if it proved `a != b`, or emitted code to check before running a version of the loop that did that.  Or with auto-vectorizing and/or unrolling, if it checked for overlap by the vector width times the unroll factor.)

This isn't a perfect example, but making loads from `b` dependent on stores from `a` should make out-of-order execution at least work hard to hide that much latency.

---

**Another easy way to create 4k aliasing would be memcpy from `src = srcpage` to `dst = dstpage + 16` or something**, with srcpage and dstpage both page-aligned of course.  A store to `dst[i]` is like `dstpage[i+16]` (in bytes, not whatever C element size), so storing `dst[i]` will happen (in program order) before a load from `src[i+16]`.  When the loop gets to that `i` value, the load will be blocked by 4k aliasing.

See [L1 memory bandwidth: 50% drop in efficiency using addresses which differ by 4096+64 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774190/l1-memory-bandwidth-50-drop-in-efficiency-using-addresses-which-differ-by-4096) for an example, with perf analysis by @HadiBrais for CPUs including IvyBridge (like your i7-3770k).

Comment: I've tried the first thing you suggested, and one based off the other article you linked but to no avail.  I've updated my question to include the disassembly of them.  Currently it seems like its storing before loading in the unrolled loop?  Or have I got my offsetting wrong and I need to subtract somehow to get the overlap?  I will try your memcpy suggestion next.

Comment: @iam: Updated my answer to clarify what I meant.  Nothing fancy, and both arrays use the *same* index.  You used `a[i]` and `b[j]`, not `b[i]`.  Anyway, look at performance counters for `ld_blocks_partial.address_alias` to tell whether you've created 4k aliasing or not.

Comment: I think I got that you meant the same index but I thought it wouldn't matter as I have j = i + offset.  Where I vary the offset to find where offsetting would prevent the problem if I found it(!).  I updated the question to include timing data and maybe I actually have found it?  But strangely not in the a[i] b[i] case but in the a[i] b[j] case - as the offset for j from i starts at zero though that's confused me a little.  (I had to uninstall vtune last year as it caused my system all sorts of problems unfortunately so I don't think I can check that counter without it?).

Comment: @iam: oh, you're on Windows?  On Linux it's super easy, just `perf stat -e cycles,ld_blocks_partial.address_alias  ./test_program`.

Comment: @PeterCordes do you know if 4k aliasing has an affect on fetching instructions?

Comment: @Noah: In what possible way?  You mean triggering a pipeline nuke if a store is at the same page-offset as a code-fetch?  No, that would be terrible.  If you mean between separate code-fetches, code is read-only, and code-fetch reloading data stores is handled by a totally separate mechanism than store-forwarding.  ([Observing stale instruction fetching on x86 with self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395557)).  Pretty sure actual pipeline nuking is delayed as long as possible, until the store is non-speculative, and probably also the jump or fall-through to RIP=that addr.

Comment: @PeterCordes well I was thinking more so: does the fetch buffer for instruction fetch act similarly to the load buffer and check for store-forwarding? I imagine not. It wouldn't necessarily be a pipeline nuke. For example false 4k aliasing does complete the store-forward, it just waits until the store complete. So with the same mechanism instruction fetch could theoretically match with the store and stall until the store completes w.o a nuke if it turned out to be a false match.

Comment: @Noah: I think code-fetch doesn't try to probe store-buffer entries at all; that would cost power and transistors, and connect distant parts of the CPU, for no benefit because actual SMC / JIT is rare.  And real SMC is always handled by a slow pipeline nuke that serializes, draining the store buffer, so correctness is maintained even if you fetched wrong machine code bytes earlier.  Retirement is in-order, and store addresses must be known for that to happen, so I'd guess that snooping the pipeline for in-flight addresses happens then, somehow?  IDK what HW allows that snooping.

Comment: @PeterCordes by the way Lewis Kesley and BeeOnRope did imo a fantastic job explaining the internals of 4K aliasing in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65949599/11322131)

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have compiled the code with options /O2 and /arch:AVX. The compiler has unrolled the inner loop 8 times and you can see there are 8 sequences of `vmulss/vaddss/vmovss`. The addresses of the `a` and `b` arrays are stored in registers `rdx` and `rdi`, respectively. The first instruction loads a single element and multiplies it by the constant, the second instruction adds the result to the corresponding element from the other array, and the third instruction stores the result into the same location. Consider two such sequences:

```
000000013F251125  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rcx*4]  
000000013F25112A  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-28h]  
000000013F25112F  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-28h],xmm2  
000000013F251134  vmulss      xmm1,xmm6,dword ptr [rdi+rax*4]  
000000013F251139  vaddss      xmm2,xmm1,dword ptr [rdx-24h]  
000000013F25113E  vmovss      dword ptr [rdx-24h],xmm2
```

`rcx` and `rax` are initialized to zero and one, respectively. `rdx` is initialized to the base address of array `a` plus 0x28. Without loss of generality, assume that the base addresses of `a` and `b` are 0x1000 and 0x2000, respectively. Then the sequence of memory accesses in program order is:

```
load 0x2000
load 0x1000
store 0x1000
load 0x2004
load 0x1004
store 0x1004
```

Is there any load that aliases a previous store? Note that you got the aliasing rules wrong (see Peter's answer and the linked answer there). In `load 0x2004` and `store 0x1000`, bits 5-11 are different. In `load 0x1004` and `store 0x1000`, bits 5-11 are equal. However, the accesses do not overlap, so there is no aliasing. It should be easy now to see why no load in the whole loop will alias a previous store.

If you change the inner loop body to:

```
a[i] *= 1.234f;
b[j] += 4.321f;
```

then the sequence for each pair of elements from each array becomes `vmulss/vmovss/vaddss/vmovss`. The memory access profile for the first two sequences is:

```
load 0x1000
store 0x1000
load 0x2000
store 0x1000
```

It's clear here that the second load aliases the first store. It's not clear to me whether there will be aliasing in all iterations due to the way the `j` index is calculated. But they do exist in this case. Using the index `i` instead will guarantee one aliasing load for each `vmulss/vmovss/vaddss/vmovss` for all iterations.

> So I am not quite sure why this doesn't show the problem from the
>   resulting timings?

Execution time only tells how fast a program got executed, not why. The observable penalty of 4K aliasing depends on the surrounding code and the total number of aliasing conditions. In addition, the generated binary code is different for different loop bodies, so if execution time changed, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's because of 4K aliasing. Yes, 4K aliasing might be a factor or even the dominant factor, but there can be other factors that have influenced execution time. The [top-down microarchitecture analysis methodology](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/wiki/toplev-manual) enables you to determine the factors that have the biggest impact on execution time.

In general, the best way to determine whether 4K aliasing occurs is by measuring `ld_blocks_partial.address_alias`. You can use [Processor Counter Monitor](https://github.com/opcm/pcm) , which works on Windows, Linux, and OSX, to measure Intel PMU events. I recommend that you do that to verify that my analysis is correct.

Comment: Processor Counter Monitor is something I didn't know about!  Not sure which helpful answer I should 'accept' now - as both are very good and I am still digging into this...