# Benchee warmup - how does it work in this library?

Tags: elixir, benchmarking

I'm playing with the *warmup* property of Benchee benchmarks increasing the warmup time gradually. I was expecting to get better results with a longer warmup time, but I get the opposite results.

For example, running the following example (extracted from the Benchee docs):

```
list = Enum.to_list(1..10_000)
map_fun = fn i -> [i, i * i] end

Benchee.run(
  %{"flat_map" => fn -> Enum.flat_map(list, map_fun) end},
  warmup: 0,
)

Benchee.run(
  %{"flat_map" => fn -> Enum.flat_map(list, map_fun) end},
  warmup: 2,
)

Benchee.run(
  %{"flat_map" => fn -> Enum.flat_map(list, map_fun) end},
  warmup: 4,
)

Benchee.run(
  %{"flat_map" => fn -> Enum.flat_map(list, map_fun) end},
  warmup: 8,
)

Benchee.run(
  %{"flat_map" => fn -> Enum.flat_map(list, map_fun) end},
  warmup: 16,
)
```

I did several invocations of the above script and I got similar results. The first execution with warmup: 0 was the best option.

```
Operating System: macOS
CPU Information: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
Number of Available Cores: 16
Available memory: 32 GB
Elixir 1.10.3
Erlang 23.0.2

Benchmark suite executing with the following configuration:
warmup: 0 ns
time: 5 s
memory time: 0 ns
parallel: 1
inputs: none specified
Estimated total run time: 5 s

Benchmarking flat_map...

Name               ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
flat_map        1.70 K      588.45 μs    ±14.33%         563 μs     1017.17 μs
Operating System: macOS
CPU Information: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
Number of Available Cores: 16
Available memory: 32 GB
Elixir 1.10.3
Erlang 23.0.2

Benchmark suite executing with the following configuration:
warmup: 2 s
time: 5 s
memory time: 0 ns
parallel: 1
inputs: none specified
Estimated total run time: 7 s

Benchmarking flat_map...

Name               ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
flat_map        1.67 K      600.24 μs    ±18.69%         563 μs     1085.84 μs
Operating System: macOS
CPU Information: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
Number of Available Cores: 16
Available memory: 32 GB
Elixir 1.10.3
Erlang 23.0.2

Benchmark suite executing with the following configuration:
warmup: 4 s
time: 5 s
memory time: 0 ns
parallel: 1
inputs: none specified
Estimated total run time: 9 s

Benchmarking flat_map...

Name               ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
flat_map        1.66 K      602.44 μs    ±18.32%         564 μs     1085.14 μs
Operating System: macOS
CPU Information: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
Number of Available Cores: 16
Available memory: 32 GB
Elixir 1.10.3
Erlang 23.0.2

Benchmark suite executing with the following configuration:
warmup: 8 s
time: 5 s
memory time: 0 ns
parallel: 1
inputs: none specified
Estimated total run time: 13 s

Benchmarking flat_map...

Name               ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
flat_map        1.65 K      606.06 μs    ±17.35%      573.98 μs     1072.98 μs
Operating System: macOS
CPU Information: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
Number of Available Cores: 16
Available memory: 32 GB
Elixir 1.10.3
Erlang 23.0.2

Benchmark suite executing with the following configuration:
warmup: 16 s
time: 5 s
memory time: 0 ns
parallel: 1
inputs: none specified
Estimated total run time: 21 s

Benchmarking flat_map...

Name               ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
flat_map        1.66 K      601.32 μs    ±17.79%         573 μs        1081 μs
```

In other VMs usually, you get better performance after a warmup phase.

How does the warmup work in BEAM? and particularly in Benchee?

Thanks in advance,
Humberto

Comment: i9-9980HK has a [max turbo of 5GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/192990/intel-core-i9-9980hk-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html) for a TDP of 45W.  It probably can't sustain that for long given thermal and power constraints ([Why can't my CPU maintain peak performance in HPC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36363613) is an extreme case; a 4.5W to 6W chip), so your first 5-second interval might have gone through warm-up and into fall-off, if this particular workload makes a lot of heat.  A short warm-up like 1 second for 1 or 2 sec of work might be the sweet spot.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @PeterCordes. I'll check it and try your suggestion. I'll let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

`warmup` in **benchee** is doing nothing more then just run your measured function for several amount of time **without** counting the results.

**benchee** creators point us out, that `warmup` concept is taken for JIT languages, where first code run will compile it and cache for future calls.

How the `warmup` can affect the results of the benchmark in BEAM? It's a question that absolutely impossible to answer, but let's try to find any `caching` mechanisms in it:

1. Atom's table can be populated during first function run, if it extensively uses atoms OR generates it on the fly.
2. May be the code **itself** (business logic) have some caching mechanism, that can somehow affect a benchmark.
3. File descriptors can be opened, if the benchmarked code uses **IO** that doesn't close the descriptors - for ex. files, http requests, etc. Also, [Page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) of the underlinge OS (better to say File System) can be affected.

If your code is straightforward, dumb and Thread|CPU bounded, `warmup` will just add some degrees to your CPU and make your cooling system to work harder, without showing any *sanity* upon the results.

Comment: Your last paragraph is not accurate for modern CPUs that adjust their clock speed in response to demand.  Several milliseconds of warm-up will get the CPU up to max turbo.    Also, if your benchmark touches memory at all, the first run will page-fault in any lazily-mapped pages, and prime the TLBs and even data caches, as well as code caches and branch prediction.  Most of these effects are a minor part of a long 5-second timed interval, but page faults for large enough buffers can be significant.  See [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987)

Comment: Thanks for your replies Virvii and Peter Cordes. I have new things from them 