# How can I account for throttling while benchmarking on a modern CPU?

Tags: performance, benchmarking

I have a python script (running under Linux fwiw) that I want to speed up by rewriting some bottleneck parts in different ways to see which one is better/faster.

I can measure the runtime or instrument it with cProfile, but the problem is that I am using a modern laptop/cpu. The runtime from run to the next is changing by as much as 5% - which is, as far as I can tell, due to various forms of CPU throttling (Temperature / Power).

This makes it very hard to check actual code performance differences. Is there some way to compensate for this and/or easily measure actual work done by the CPU?

Comment: Well thermal throttling is not the only reason that can explain such a difference (although is plays a significant role). In fact there are *plenty of source of slowdown*. This include for example contexts switches (eg. browsers are good applications to disturb running benchmarks, but even things like ssh connections can have a tiny impact), the allocated memory alignment, the address of the code itself, the distribution of allocated pages in virtual&physical memory, OS scheduling and the behaviour of the OS for its own internal data structures, not to mention I/Os.

Comment: [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-TLSBdHe1A) explains partially that and provide a tool to better deal with such a statistical noise. Not all source of slowdown can be removed. Many processors do not provide a way to set a fixed frequency and the mainstream operating systems are far from being stable in terms of performance (real-time systems are better for that). HPC systems often succeed to reduce the noise to 1-2% by only running few critical processes, tuning the OS (eg. less kernel calls, thread binding) and the processor config (eg. frequency & memory control).

Answer (score 3):

It may be viable to disable turbo or whatever other vendors call their boost clocks, so the clock frequency stays at the baseline frequency the laptop can sustain.

Running the CPU a lot slower (like 1.6GHz instead of 3 or something) changes the relative cost of a cache miss to DRAM vs. a branch mispredict, because DRAM still takes a similar amount of nanoseconds but that's a lot fewer clock cycles.  So it's not perfect if the thing you're comparing involves that kind of tradeoff.  Similarly for I/O vs. CPU.

**If you can get your system to run at a couple different low but stable frequencies**, you can extrapolate performance at higher frequencies even for workloads that are sensitive to memory latency and maybe bandwidth: Dr. Bandwidth explains how in [a blog article with slides from his HPC conference talk on it](https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2020/04/02/the-surprising-effectiveness-of-non-overlapping-sensitivity-based-performance-models/).

---

For mostly CPU-bound stuff (not memory or I/O), `perf stat ./my_program` can be useful: **look at time in core clock cycles instead of seconds**.  This doesn't even try to control for relative differences in cache miss costs vs. on-core effects, but is convenient if you're on Linux or another OS that has a handy profiler that can use HW performance counters.  (Usually only works on bare metal, not in a VM; most VMs don't virtualize the performance-monitoring unit.)
If L3 cache misses are a significant part of the performance cost, you'd expect core clock cycles to vary with frequency, again because of RAM becoming relatively faster / lower latency compared to the CPU core, meaning out-of-order exec can hide more of the latency of a cache miss.

See also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291987/idiomatic-way-of-performance-evaluation) for other benchmark considerations not related to keeping frequency stable.

See [Why can't my ultraportable laptop CPU maintain peak performance in HPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363613/why-cant-my-ultraportable-laptop-cpu-maintain-peak-performance-in-hpc) for a good example of an ultraportable laptop's CPU frequency vs. time when running power-intensive loads, and the CPU-design reasons for it being that way.

Comment: If you can run at different frequencies (even if they are all lower than you want), it is possible to make accurate extrapolations to performance at higher frequencies.  See https://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2020/04/02/the-surprising-effectiveness-of-non-overlapping-sensitivity-based-performance-models/.