# What do the CPU parameters mean?

Tags: cpu

My processor is tagged with 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz   1.80 GHz. My question is why there are two values, i.e. 3GHz and 1.8GHz? What are they referred to respectively?

Comment: Did you mean 4.8 GHz (the turbo frequency) or 1.2 GHz (the low thermal design power base frequency) when you wrote 1.8 GHz? 3.0 GHz is the base frequency for the high thermal design power. See https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/208664/intel-core-i71185g7-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz-with-ipu.html

Comment: Related: [Why can't my ultraportable laptop CPU maintain peak performance in HPC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36363613)