# Application performance vs Peak performance

Tags: hpc, supercomputers

I have questions about real application performance running on a cluster vs cluster peak performance.

Let's say one HPC cluster report that it has peak performance of 1 Petaflops. How is this calculated?
To me, it seems that there are two measuring matrixes. One is the performance calculated based on the hardware. The other one is from running HPL? Is my understanding correct? 
When I am reading one real application running on the system at full scale, the developer mentions that it could achieve 10% of the peak performance. How is this measured and why it can't achieve peak performance?

Thanks

Comment: OK. HPL is a benchmark used in top500 list to rank supercomputers in the world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peak performance is what the system is **theoretically** able to deliver. It is the product of the total number of CPU cores, the core clock frequency, and the number of FLOPs one core makes per clock tick. That performance can never be reached in practice because no real application consists of 100% fully vectorised tight loops that only operate on data held in the L1 data cache. In many cases data doesn't even fit in the last-level cache and the memory interface is usually not fast enough to deliver data at the same rate at which the CPU is able to process it. One ubiquitous example from HPC is the multiplication of a sparse matrix with a vector. It is so memory intensive (i.e. many loads and stores per arithmetic operation) that on many platforms it only achieves a fraction of the peak performance.

Things get even worse when multiple nodes are networked together on a massive scale as data transfers could introduce huge additional delays. Performance in those cases is determined mainly by the ratio of local data processing and data transfer. HPL is a particularly good in that aspect - it does a lot of vectorised local processing and does not move much data across the CPUs/nodes. That's **not** the case with many real-world parallel programs and also the reason why many are questioning the applicability of HPL in assessing cluster performance nowadays. Alternative benchmarks are already emerging, for example the [HPCG benchmark](https://software.sandia.gov/hpcg/about.php) (from the people who brought you HPL).

Answer (score 2):

The theoretical (peak) value is based on the capability of each individual core in the cluster, which depends on clock frequency, number of floating point units, parallel instruction issuing  capacity, vector register sizes, etc. which are design characteristics of the core. The flops/s count for each core in the cluster is then aggregated to get the cluster flops/s count.

*For a car the equivalent theoretical performance would be the maximum speed it can reach given the specification of its engine.*

For a program to reach the theoretical count, it has to perform specific operations in a specific order so that the instruction-level parallelism is maximum and all floating-point units are working constantly without delay due to synchronization or memory access, etc. (See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389648/how-do-i-achieve-the-theoretical-maximum-of-4-flops-per-cycle) for more insights)

*For a car, it is equivalent to measuring top speed on a straight line with no wind.*

But of course, chances that such a program computes something of interest are small. So benchmarks like HPL use actual problems in linear algebra, with a highly optimized and tuned implementation, but which is still imperfect due to IO operations and the fact that the order of operations is not optimal.

*For a car, it could be compared to measuring the top average speed on a race track with straight lines, curves, etc.*

If the program requires a lot of network, or disk communications, which are operations that require a lot of clock cycle, then the CPU has often to stay idle waiting for data before it can perform arithmetic operations, effectively wasting away a lot of computing power. Then, the actual performance is estimated by dividing the number of floating points operations (addition and multiplications) the program is performing by the time it takes to perform them.

*For a car, this would correspond to measuring the top average speed in town with red lights, etc. by calculating the length of the trip divided by the time needed to accomplish it.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I am clear now.