# why is Rpeak different from Rmax when measuring performance?

Tags: performance, flops, supercomputers, linpack

```
Rmax is maximum performance 
RPeak is theorotical maximum performance.
```

but why can't supercomputers reach Rpeak. what causes the inefficency?

an explanation to the cause of inefficency.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677264/what-is-rmax-rpeak-ratio-in-terms-of-supercomputer and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979113/application-performance-vs-peak-performance/26012275#26012275 answer your question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application performance vs Peak performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979113/application-performance-vs-peak-performance)