# C++: stress windows system

Tags: c++, windows, stress-testing

I want to write a program in c++ that are able to stress a windows 7 system. In my intention I want that this program brings the cpu usage to 100%, using all ram installed.

I have tried with a big FOR cycle that run a simple multiplication at every step: the cpu usage increase but the ram used remain low.

What is the best approach to reach my target?!

Comment: For memory stress, use `VirtualAlloc` API to commit as many large buffers as you can, make sure to touch all pages so everything is RAM.

Comment: Do you understand why your code does not increase memory usage?

Comment: One core will never bring the CPU at 100%: you have to use all the available threads plus an intensive task, which should avoid useless I/O or things which it will be waiting for.
You may consider something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389648/how-do-i-achieve-the-theoretical-maximum-of-4-flops-per-cycle).

Answer (score 0):

In an OS agnostic way, you could allocate and fill heap memory obtained with [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) (so do some computation with that zone), or in C++ with `operator new`. Be sure to test against failure of `malloc`. And increase the size of your zone progressively.

Comment: And when it _does_ fail, step down in size and retry.  Of course, this only "uses" RAM in a theoretical sense. If you don't write to that RAM, it's not stressed at all.

Comment: The "fill" verb was meaning to *write* the malloc-ed memory

Comment: Sorry, mistook that for an intent to allocate phsyical RAM (you linked against a Linux man page, and Linux famously does not allocate RAM when you just call malloc). I meant that to stress the memory, you should be writing **a lot**. Don't fill it once, as that just ends up in swap.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is ability to stress CPU and RAM utilization (and not necessarily writing a program), try HeavyLoad which is free and does just that http://www.jam-software.com/heavyload/

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote a test program for this using multithreading and Mersenne Primes as the algorithm for stress testing**

[image]

The code first determines the number of cores on the machine (WINDOWS only guys, sorry!!)

```
NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemBasicInformation, &BasicInformation, sizeof(SYSTEM_BASIC_INFORMATION), NULL);
```

It then runs a test method to spawn a thread for each core

```
// make sure we've got at least as many threads as cores
for (int i = 0; i < this->BasicInformation.NumberOfProcessors; i++)
{
    threads.push_back(thread(&CpuBenchmark::MersennePrimes, CpuBenchmark()));
}
```

running our load

```
BOOL CpuBenchmark::IsPrime(ULONG64 n)  // function determines if the number n is prime.
{
    for (ULONG64 i = 2; i * i < n; i++)

        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}


ULONG64 CpuBenchmark::Power2(ULONG64 n)     //function returns 2 raised to power of n
{
    ULONG64 square = 1;
    for (ULONG64 i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        square *= 2;
    }
    return square;

}

VOID CpuBenchmark::MersennePrimes()
{

    ULONG64 i;
    ULONG64 n;

    for (n = 2; n <= 61; n++)      
    {                              
        if (IsPrime(n) == 1)      
        {
            i = Power2(n) - 1;
            if (IsPrime(i) == 1) {
                // dont care just want to stress the CPU
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and waits for all threads to complete

```
// wait for them all to finish
    for (auto& th : threads)
        th.join();
```

Full article and source code on my blog site

http://malcolmswaine.com/c-cpu-stress-test-algorithm-mersenne-primes/