# Combining integers and floating point numbers: performance considerations

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, type-conversion

I have a complex set of template functions which do calculations in a loop, combining floating point numbers and the uint32_t loop indices. I was surprised to observe that for this kind of functions, my test code runs faster with double precision floating point numbers than with single precision ones.

As a test, I changed the format of my indices to uint16_t. After this, both the double and float version of the program were faster (as expected), but now the float version was significantly faster than the double version. I also tested the program with uint64_t indices. In this case the double and the float version are equally slow.

I imagine that this is because an uint32_t fits into the mantissa of a double but not into a float. Once the indices type was reduced to uint16_t, they also fit into the mantissa of a float and a conversion should be trivial. In case of uint64_t, the conversion to double also needs rounding, which would explain why both versions perform equally.

Can anybody confirm this explanation?

EDIT: Using int or long as index type, the program runs as fast as for unit16_t. I guess this speaks against what I suspected first.

EDIT: I compiled the program for windows on an x86 architecture.

EDIT: Here is a piece of code that reproduces the effect of double being faster as float for uint32_t and both cases being equally fast for int. Please do not comment on the usefulness of this code. It is a modified fragment of code reproducing the effect which does nothing sensible.

The main file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

typedef short spectraType;
typedef int intermediateValue;
typedef double returnType;

#include "Preprocess_t.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t numberOfBins = 10000;
    const size_t numberOfSpectra = 500;
    const size_t peakWidth = 25;

    bool startPeak = false;
    short peakHeight;

    Preprocess<short, returnType> myPreprocessor;
    std::vector<returnType> processedSpectrum;

    std::vector<std::vector<short>> spectra(numberOfSpectra, std::vector<short>(numberOfBins));


    std::vector<float> peakShape(peakWidth);

    LARGE_INTEGER freq, start, stop;
    double time_ms;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);


    for (size_t i = 0; i < peakWidth; ++i)
    {
        peakShape[i] = static_cast<float>(exp(-(i - peakWidth / 2.0) *(i - peakWidth / 2.0) / 10.0));
    }


    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfSpectra; ++i)
    {
        size_t j = 0;
        for (; j < 200; ++j)
        {
            spectra[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }

        for (size_t k = 0; k < 25; ++k)
        {
            spectra[i][j] = static_cast<short>(16383 * peakShape[k]);
            j++;
        }

        for (; j < numberOfBins; ++j)
        {
            startPeak = !static_cast<bool>(abs(rand()) % (numberOfBins / 4));

            if (startPeak)
            {
                peakHeight = rand() % 16384;

                for (size_t k = 0; k < 25 && j< numberOfBins; ++k)
                {
                    spectra[i][j] = peakHeight * peakShape[k] + rand() % 100;
                    j++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                spectra[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < numberOfBins; ++j)
        {
            double temp = 1000.0*exp(-(static_cast<float>(j) / (numberOfBins / 3.0)))*sin(static_cast<float>(j) / (numberOfBins / 10.0));
            spectra[i][j] -= static_cast<short>(1000.0*exp(-(static_cast<float>(j) / (numberOfBins / 3.0)))*sin(static_cast<float>(j) / (numberOfBins / 10.0)));
        }

    }

    // This is where the critical code is called

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSpectra; ++i)
    {
        myPreprocessor.SetSpectrum(&spectra[i], 1000, &processedSpectrum);
        myPreprocessor.CorrectBaseline(30, 2.0);
    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&stop);

    time_ms = static_cast<double>(stop.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / static_cast<double>(freq.QuadPart);

    std::cout << "time spend preprocessing: " << time_ms << std::endl;

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

And the included header Preprocess_t.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

//typedef unsigned int indexType;
typedef unsigned short indexType;

template<typename T, typename Out_Type>
class Preprocess
{
public:
    Preprocess() :threshold(1), sdev(1), laserPeakThreshold(500), a(0), b(0), firstPointUsedAfterLaserPeak(0) {};
    ~Preprocess() {};

    void SetSpectrum(std::vector<T>* input, T laserPeakThreshold, std::vector<Out_Type>* processedSpectrum); ///@note We need the laserPeakThresholdParameter for the baseline correction, not onla for the shift.

    void CorrectBaseline(indexType numberOfPoints, Out_Type thresholdFactor);

private:

    void LinFitValues(indexType beginPoint);
    Out_Type SumOfSquareDiffs(Out_Type x, indexType n);

    Out_Type LinResidualSumOfSquareDist(indexType beginPoint);

    std::vector<T>* input;
    std::vector<Out_Type>* processedSpectrum;

    std::vector<indexType> fitWave_X;
    std::vector<Out_Type> fitWave;
    Out_Type threshold;
    Out_Type sdev;
    T laserPeakThreshold;
    Out_Type a, b;
    indexType firstPointUsedAfterLaserPeak;
    indexType numberOfPoints;
};

template<typename T, typename Out_Type>
void Preprocess<T, Out_Type>::CorrectBaseline(indexType numberOfPoints, Out_Type thresholdFactor)
{
    this->numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;

    indexType numberOfBins = input->size();
    indexType firstPointUsedAfterLaserPeak = 0;

    indexType positionInFitWave = 0;

    positionInFitWave = firstPointUsedAfterLaserPeak;

    for (indexType i = firstPointUsedAfterLaserPeak; i < numberOfBins - numberOfPoints; i++) {
        LinFitValues(positionInFitWave);
        processedSpectrum->at(i + numberOfPoints) = input->at(i + numberOfPoints) - static_cast<Out_Type>(a + b*(i + numberOfPoints));


        positionInFitWave++;
        fitWave[positionInFitWave + numberOfPoints - 1] = input->at(i + numberOfPoints - 1);
        fitWave_X[positionInFitWave + numberOfPoints - 1] = i + numberOfPoints - 1;

    }
}

template<typename T, typename Out_Type>
void Preprocess<T, Out_Type>::LinFitValues(indexType beginPoint)
{
    Out_Type y_mean, x_mean, SSxy, SSxx, normFactor;
    y_mean = x_mean = SSxy = SSxx = normFactor = static_cast<Out_Type>(0);
    indexType endPoint = beginPoint + numberOfPoints;
    Out_Type temp;

    if ((fitWave_X[endPoint - 1] - fitWave_X[beginPoint]) == numberOfPoints)
    {
        x_mean = (fitWave_X[endPoint - 1] - fitWave_X[beginPoint]) / static_cast<Out_Type>(2);

        for (indexType i = beginPoint; i < endPoint; i++) {
            y_mean += fitWave[i];
        }

        y_mean /= numberOfPoints;

        SSxx = SumOfSquareDiffs(x_mean, fitWave_X[endPoint - 1]) - SumOfSquareDiffs(x_mean, fitWave_X[beginPoint]);

        for (indexType i = beginPoint; i < endPoint; i++)
        {
            SSxy += (fitWave_X[i] - x_mean)*(fitWave[i] - y_mean);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (indexType i = beginPoint; i < endPoint; i++) {
            y_mean += fitWave[i];
            x_mean += fitWave_X[i];
        }

        y_mean /= numberOfPoints;
        x_mean /= numberOfPoints;

        for (indexType i = beginPoint; i < endPoint; i++)
        {
            temp = (fitWave_X[i] - x_mean);
            SSxy += temp*(fitWave[i] - y_mean);
            SSxx += temp*temp;
        }
    }

    b = SSxy / SSxx;
    a = y_mean - b*x_mean;
}

template<typename T, typename Out_Type>
inline Out_Type Preprocess<T, Out_Type>::SumOfSquareDiffs(Out_Type x, indexType n)
{
    return n*x*x + n*(n - 1)*x + ((n - 1)*n*(2 * n - 1)) / static_cast<Out_Type>(6);
}

template<typename T, typename Out_Type>
Out_Type Preprocess<T, Out_Type>::LinResidualSumOfSquareDist(indexType beginPoint) 
{
    Out_Type sumOfSquares = 0;
    Out_Type temp;

    for (indexType i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; ++i) {
        temp = fitWave[i + beginPoint] - (a + b*fitWave_X[i + beginPoint]);
        sumOfSquares += temp*temp;
    }
    return sumOfSquares;
}


template<typename T, typename Out_Type>
inline void Preprocess<T, Out_Type>::SetSpectrum(std::vector<T>* input, T laserPeakThreshold, std::vector<Out_Type>* processedSpectrum)
{
    this->input = input;
    fitWave_X.resize(input->size());
    fitWave.resize(input->size());
    this->laserPeakThreshold = laserPeakThreshold;
    this->processedSpectrum = processedSpectrum;
    processedSpectrum->resize(input->size());
}
```

Comment: This is very much architecture-dependent, but yes: if your float_type's mantissa equals sizeof( int_type ), you might expect speedup on *some* architectures.

Comment: Try it with `int` for the loop index.

Comment: what compiler flags are you using? optimization turned on?

Comment: You can get quite a bit of insight by examining the generated assembly. Why don't you share the code? Perhaps someone might go to the trouble of doing that

Comment: @PeteBecker Ok, that version also results in the float version being faster. That speaks against my reasoning.

Comment: @tobi303 /O2 on VC2015 all other flags are the default flags of visual studio 2015.

Comment: @Smeeheey I managed to produce a (still large for SO) piece of code that reproduces the effect.

Comment: Arrgh, windows. Sigh... :(

Comment: @Smeeheey Sorry for that. Nevertheless, the code is portable except for the QueryPerformance counter stuff used for the timing. The #pragma once could be changed to a header guard define and  #include "stdafx.h" can be removed if not using visual studio.

Comment: Yeah that's OK. I've converted it to Linux already

Comment: Side Note: Do not use vector::at in performance critical sections (I personally, never use vector::at).

Comment: @DieterLücking You're right, I never used it before and didn't notice that it checks for out of bounds indices.

Answer (score 1):

You are using MSVC? I had a similar effect when I implemented code that essentially was a matrix-multiplication plus a vector addition. Here, I thought that `float`s would be faster because they can be better SIMD-parallelized as more can be packed in the SSE registers. However, using `double`s was much faster.

After some investigation, I figured out from the assembler code that the float's need conversion from the internal FPU precision and this rounding was consuming most of the runtime. [You can change the FP model to something that is faster with the cost of reduced precision.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) [There is also some discussion in older threads here at SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584637/double-or-float-which-is-faster)

Comment: I understand that floats are not necessarily faster than doubles. What confuses me is the gain in execution speed of about 30 % just by changing the type of the indices from unsigned int to int or long or unsigned short.