# How to write a C++ float literal?

Tags: c++, literals

`result` is `float` and I could code this three ways:

- `if (result < 0)`
- `if (result < 0.)`
- `if (result < 0.f)`

As I understand it,

- `0` is implicitly `int`,
- `0.` is implicitly `double`
- and `0.f` is `float`.

I'd prefer to use the first method since it is clear and simple but am I forcing a type conversion by using it?

Comment: The compiler already knows that you need 0.f, the conversion is applied at compile-time.  So favor the syntax that is most readable.

Comment: The compiler in general can optimise better than you or me.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `if (result < 0.f)` because when I see `if (result < 0)` I tend to think that `result` is integral.

Comment: #2 looks like a typo, dont like it at all

Comment: My personal preference is `if (result < 0.0)`. Using `0.0` tells the user that the value is floating-point. The fact that it's `double` rather than `float` is less important, and any implicit conversion is exact. (And, depending on the context, it's entirely possible that `result` should have been `double` rather than `float` in the first place.) You can have a `.` a the end of a floating-point constant, but I found `0.0` significantly more readable than `0.`.

Comment: Somewhat OT: Be careful when using comparison operators on floating-point numbers. Due to rounding errors, the results may be surprising. E.g. `float f=0.0f; for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) f+=0.01f;` – the result will not be equal to `1.0f` on an IEEE platform. (For this reason, I prefer to be explicit in writing `0.0f` in such a situation so that it's obvious that the comparison makes an assumption about floating-point behavior.)

Answer (score 8):

Conceptually yes, conversions are made.

But you should defer such micro-considerations to the compiler and write what's clearest which, for me is

```
if (result < 0)
```

If you are ever in any doubt, check the generated assembly (very easy with https://gcc.godbolt.org/).

Finally, when deciding to use a `float` over a `double`, consider [double or float, which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584637/double-or-float-which-is-faster)

Comment: I'd go further and say that `0` is best conversion-wise as well. At least `0` is never gonna cause a conversion on `result`, which `0.` might.

Comment: Btw, clearest is a little opinion based. `result < 0.f` is clear for me, `result < 0.` is misleading type of `result`. `result < 0` is "neutral".

Comment: @Jarod42: You're right; I've softened the answer a little.