# Double divided by double and by integer: which one is better?

Tags: c++, c

I always assume that dividing a double by an integer will lead to faster code because the compiler will select the better microcode to compute:

```
double a;
double b = a/3.0;
double c = a/3; // will compute faster than b
```

For a single operation it does not matter, but for repetitive operations it can make difference. Is my assumption always correct or compiler or CPU  dependent or whatever?

The same question applies for multiplication; i.e. will `3 * a` be faster than `3.0 * a`?

Comment: If the second operand is constant, there will be no difference.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no mixing of types internally in the arithmetic/floating point unit. At the machine level both operands are of the same type... converted previously if needed. `a` and `3.0` have the same type (`double`)... `a` and `3` require a (implicit) conversion (by the compiler, not at runtime).

Comment: Read this first :) 
Floating points are handled in hardware (unless you have a small processor)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584637/double-or-float-which-is-faster

Comment: Is there a difference between C and C++? If so, the question should clarify which language is meant. If not, this should be addressed in an answer.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mean mostly for c++. But I think it will apply the same for C because compiler's math arithmetic is the same.

Comment: Compilers do not generate "_microcode_" - on some CISC architectures individual _machine instructions_ are implemented in microcode - the microcode is intrinsic to the processor.  There is no machine instruction to divide a `double` by an `int` to produce a `double` result - there is no likely performance benefit and the need would be niche at best, the compiler will generate FPU instructions on platforms with an FPU.  Even with software floating point (no FPU), there is probably no significant advantage in having a specific `double`/`int` operator overload.

Answer (score 8):

Your assumption is *not* correct because both your divide operations will be performed with two `double` operands. In the second case, `c = a/3`, the integer literal will be converted to a `double` value by the compiler before any code is generated.

From [this Draft C++ Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf):

> ##### 8.3 Usual arithmetic conversions          [expr.arith.conv]
>
> <sup>1</sup>    Many binary operators
> that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause
> conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
> yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This
> pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which are
> defined as follows:
> …
> <sup>(1.3)</sup> –
> Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted
> to double.

---

Note that, in [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **§6.3.1.8** (Usual arithmetic conversions) has equivalent (indeed, near-identical) text.

Comment: Note that, for a target architecture where there is an optimization to be had using code that divides a `double` by an `int`, then any decent compiler will use such code for a literal like `3.0`, just as it would for `3` - it will surely spot that the fractional part is zero.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The integer operand is implicitly converted to a double, so they end up practically equivalent.