# C program to find the sum of factorials

Tags: c, for-loop, math, sum, factorial

I was trying to compute the sum of series which involves factorials.

The series is: 1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + ...

btw 3! = 1 x 2 x 3

4! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4

...so on, it continues like this for every number

This is the code I've written to run the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    /* Any problems with the variables? */
        
    int i, lim, fact = 1;
    float sum = 0.0, term;
    
    printf("Enter the limit for the sum of series: ");
    scanf("%d", &lim);
    
    /* Any problems in the loop? */
    
    for (i = 1; i <= lim; i++) {
        fact *= i;
        term = 1 / fact;
        sum += fact; 
    }

    printf ("%f is the sum of the series\n", sum);
}
```

Is there any syntax error here that I just can't see or something, or is it a problem of the compiler. If so, I'm using gcc on ubuntu. Nevertheless, I'm not getting the correct output.

Comment: If there is a syntax error, your compiler will immediately tell you because it cannot compile your code in that case. But you have other errors: `void main` is wrong. `main` is defined to have return type `int` in hosted environments. And you do not check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Why are you adding `sum += fact`? That is not what your formula tells you to do.

Comment: term is always 0 because you're dividing integers (you probably want 1.0 / fact) and you're not adding the right thing to sum. Also fact will quickly overflow because factorials grow quickly.

Comment: `sum += fact;` should be `sum += term;`?

Comment: In addition to `sum += term`, you need to correct `term = 1 / fact` to `term = 1.0 / fact`.

Comment: `float` **no, no, no** always prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values (except when you have a very strong reason to do otherwise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code.

**The first one,** is very common when we start learning C

`1 / fact` must be replaced by `1.0f / fact`

Why? Because in C, `1 / 2` is performed using integer arithmetic and returns `0`. If you want to perform computation using floating numbers you must force at least one argument being a floating number, this can be done by `1.0/2`, `1/2.0` or `1.0/2.0`. The previous expressions will be evaluated using `double` floating number type (which is the C default type for floating number). If you want to use simple precision floating numbers, `float`, you can use `1.0f`

**the second one** is certainly an inadvertent error:

`sum += fact;` must be replace by `sum += term;`

---

Here is a "working" code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
main()
{
  /*Any problems with the variables ?*/

  int i, lim, fact = 1;
  float sum = 0.0, term;

  printf("Enter the limit for the sum of series: ");
  scanf("%d", &lim);

  /*Any problems in the loop ? */

  for (i = 1; i <= lim; i++)
  {
    fact *= i;
    term = 1. / fact; /* instead of 1/fact */
    sum += term;      /* instead of sum += fact */
  }

  printf("%f is the sum of the series\n", sum);
}
```

> Enter the limit for the sum of series: 5
>
> 1.716667 is the sum of the series

---

There is a more subtle error. By instance, if you want `lim = 50`,

> Enter the limit for the sum of series: 50
>
> inf is the sum of the series

The reason is that `50!` is way too big to be stored in an `int`.

The solution is to compute directly `1/i!` using floating number (and not `i!` using `int` then `1/i!`)

A modified program, that also uses `double` for an higher precision is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
main()
{
  /*Any problems with the variables ?*/

  int lim;
  double sum = 0.0, term = 1.0;

  printf("Enter the limit for the sum of series: ");
  scanf("%d", &lim);

  /*Any problems in the loop ? */

  for (int i = 1; i <= lim; i++)
  {
    term = term / i;
    sum += term;
  }

  printf("%f is the sum of the series\n", sum);
}
```

that now works, even when `lim=50`

---

Do not be discouraged by these mistakes. These are mistakes we all made when we learned C !

---

Expected result:

exp(1) = exp(0) + sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/i!

thus your expected result is exp(1)-exp(0) = 1.718281828459045....

Comment: You might also suggest using `double` type instead of `float` to increase the precision and output more decimals with `%.10f` or more.  Also fix the `main()` return type.

Comment: @chqrlie yes you are right !

Comment: I had one doubt, does the variable type like in this case float or double affect the compiling time in any way?

Comment: Totally negligible for this example. You can read https://stackoverflow.com/a/4584707/2001017

Answer (score 2):

At least these problems:

`1 / fact` is `int` division with an `int` quotient.

Try `1.0f / fact` for a `float` division and `float` quotient.

`sum += fact;` --> `sum += term;` is code should sum the terms.

Answer (score -2):

Try it with int main() once and let me know whether it is working or not

Comment: Or direct main()

Comment: There is alot more wrong with the code than that. So this is in no way a complete answer.