# Why would adding a line of computation decrease runtime?

Tags: java

When testing an answer to one of my [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232446/float-or-double/11238970#comment15086100_11238970), I wrote this:

```
public static long timeDouble(int iters) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (; iters >=0; iters--) {
        double a = 1.2, b = 2.246, c = 4.4924, d = 8.98488, e = 17.969772;
        a = Math.sqrt(a);
        b = Math.cos(b);
        c = Math.sin(c);
        d = Math.tan(d);
        e = a + b - c * d / (e + 1);
        e = Math.pow(e, e);
    }
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
}
```

This method's run time was an average of 414ms (using 1000000 iterations). However, something possessed me to add this line:

```
e = e + d - c * b / (a + 1);
```

immediately before `e = Math.pow(e, e);` With the addition of this line, the time for calculating this method dropped to an average of 206 ms (using the same test conditions).

What is causing this?

Comment: Maybe the value of `e` is decreased by that equation, and then `Math.pow(e, e)` will take less time to execute.

Comment: It's probably due to the fact that Math.pow(e, e) is using less processor cycles, perhaps due to the fact that e is smaller.

Comment: The above posters are probably correct, but I'd generally steer away from this kind of microbenchmarking, it has quite a few pitfalls. http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.microBenchmark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in the loop are constant, they don't depend on `iters`. and therefore the values are the same all the time.

```
    double a = 1.2, b = 2.246, c = 4.4924, d = 8.98488, e = 17.969772;
    a = Math.sqrt(a);
    b = Math.cos(b);
    c = Math.sin(c);
    d = Math.tan(d);
    e = a + b - c * d / (e + 1);
    e = Math.pow(e, e);
```

In the first version you were calculating `e` to be the value 17.969772 ^ 17.969772.  In the second you are calculating `e` to be the value 0.69761863561124537 ^ 0.69761863561124537.  This is (by your own evidence) easier to computer.