# Storing decimals in resource folders

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-resources

One of the requirements of my code is that an alpha value is used. I want to program my application so that at some point in the future, I can easily change this value.

My understanding is that resources are built specifically for this purpose. Alpha needs to be between 0 and 1.

I wondered if there was a more elegant solution than setting the value to an integer between 1 and 100 in the integer resource folder, then dividing by 100 in the code.

Current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
<!-- choose a value for alpha, it will be divided by 100. 
valid values lie between 0 and 100.-->
<item name = "exponential_filter_alpha" format="">9</item>    
</resources>
```

I saw a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8780360/1014849
But that required floats, doubles are not available via that method.

Comment: Can you explain why you must use `double` instead of `float`?

Comment: My understanding is that you don't want to use floats when a double would suffice, or use a double when an int would work? Is it fine to just use a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I understand your questions as a performance question.

Saving and using an `int` in resources instead of a `float` should not be noticeable in the performance at all. By that note I think saving an `int` and then dividing by 100 all the time would be silly, when you could just as well save a float. Also noting that when you divide your `int` it will get implicitly converted to a `double` anyway.

You say that you use the value for an `alpha` value, and you might only need the precision 1 to 100, using a float for that kind of precision is very reasonable, and also reasonable for an `alpha` value.

You might want to read [Float or Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232446/float-or-double)

Comment: You are correct, it is a performance question. Thank you. The link was helpful and I appreciate your input. I was coming at it from a best practice pov.

Answer (score 1):

There is an integer resource. See here: [Resource Types - More Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html).  Then you can call [`getResources().getInteger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getInteger%28int%29)`(R.integer.exponential_filter_alpha)` in your Activity to get the integer value, then divide by 100 as you requested.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was currently using but wondered if there was a more elegant method.

Comment: I don't understand how you get more elegant that that.  Its pretty straightforward and you have all your values in one spot as opposed to hard-coding them in different areas. You don't need to have all your values in different files either.  You can have `<integer/>`'s and `<bool/>`'s all in a common constants.xml or config.xml file in your `res/values` folder.  If your curious, you can always see how Google organized their [values folder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/).

Comment: Yes we're in agreement with regards to the resource folder route. What would be perfect would be if I could store doubles in the resource folder, which unfortunately I cannot . I was looking for a solution to this problem. Storing floats in the resource folder turns out to be the best (seemingly). Thank you very much for your input Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<item name="prim_alpha" format="float" type="dimen">0.87</item>
```