# Is it possible that doubles are x2 FASTER than float?

Tags: c#, performance, intel, processor

I performed some benchmarking to compare doubles and floats performance. I was very surprised to see that doubles are much faster than floats.

I saw some discussion about that, for example:

[Is using double faster than float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426165/is-using-double-faster-than-float)

[Are doubles faster than floats in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158889/are-doubles-faster-than-floats-in-c)

Most of them said that it is possible that double and float performance will be similar , because of double-precision optimization, etc. . But I saw a **x2 performance improvement when using doubles**!! How is it possible? What makes it worst, is that I'm using a 32-bit machine which do expected to perform better for floats according to some posts...

I used C# to check it precisely but I see that similar C++ implementation have similar behavior.

Code I used to check it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  double[,] doubles = new double[64, 64];
  float[,] floats = new float[64, 64];

  System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

  s.Restart();
  CalcDoubles(doubles);
  s.Stop();
  long doubleTime = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  s.Restart();
  CalcFloats(floats);
  s.Stop();
  long floatTime = s.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  Console.WriteLine("Doubles time: " + doubleTime + " ms");
  Console.WriteLine("Floats time: " + floatTime + " ms");
}

private static void CalcDoubles(double[,] arr)
{
  unsafe
  {
    fixed (double* p = arr)
    {
      for (int b = 0; b < 192 * 12; ++b)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < 64; ++j)
          {
            double* addr = (p + i * 64 + j);
            double arrij = *addr;
            arrij = arrij == 0 ? 1.0f / (i * j) : arrij * (double)i / j;
            *addr = arrij;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

private static void CalcFloats(float[,] arr)
{
  unsafe
  {
    fixed (float* p = arr)
    {
      for (int b = 0; b < 192 * 12; ++b)
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < 64; ++j)
          {
            float* addr = (p + i * 64 + j);
            float arrij = *addr;
            arrij = arrij == 0 ? 1.0f / (i * j) : arrij * (float)i / j;
            *addr = arrij;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using a very weak notebook: Intel Atom N455 processor (dual core, 1.67GHz, 32bit) with 2GB RAM.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Notice that the counter is incremented in the same offset on both doubles and floats cases (it is manually calculated in the for loop).

Comment: You don't need unsafe code to reproduce this. The effect disappears if you remove the assignment back into the array.

Comment: You are right, it happens also on my machine. And why is that? Maybe cache writeback/writethrough policy (as maybe previously said)?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi That supports the hypothesis that the calculations are being performed using double precision and that the additional processing time for the floats is devoted to converting them to 32-bit format for storage in the array.

Answer (score 10):

This looks the jitter optimizer drops the ball here, it doesn't suppress a redundant store in the float case.  The hot code is the `1.0f / (i * j)` calculation since all array values are 0.  The x86 jitter generates:

```
01062928  mov         eax,edx                     ; eax = i
0106292A  imul        eax,esi                     ; eax = i * j
0106292D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax     ; store to mem
01062930  fild        dword ptr [ebp-10h]         ; convert to double 
01062933  fstp        dword ptr [ebp-10h]         ; redundant store, convert to float
01062936  fld         dword ptr [ebp-10h]         ; redundant load
01062939  fld1                                    ; 1.0f
0106293B  fdivrp      st(1),st                    ; 1.0f / (i * j)
0106293D  fstp        dword ptr [ecx]             ; arrij = result
```

The x64 jitter:

```
00007FFCFD6440B0  cvtsi2ss    xmm0,r10d           ; (float)(i * j)
00007FFCFD6440B5  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [7FFCFD644118h]  ; 1.0f
00007FFCFD6440BD  divss       xmm1,xmm0           ; 1.0f / (i * j)
00007FFCFD6440C1  cvtss2sd    xmm0,xmm1           ; redundant store 
00007FFCFD6440C5  cvtsd2ss    xmm0,xmm0           ; redundant load
00007FFCFD6440C9  movss       dword ptr [rax+r11],xmm0  ; arrij = result
```

I marked the superfluous instructions with "redundant".  The optimizer did manage to eliminate them in the *double* version so that code runs faster.

The redundant stores are actually present in the IL generated by the C# compiler, it is the job of the optimizer to detect and remove them.  Notable is that both the x86 and the x64 jitter have this flaw so it looks like a general oversight in the optimizer algorithm.

The x64 code is especially noteworthy for converting the float result to double and then back to float again, suggesting that the underlying problem is a data type conversion that it doesn't know how to suppress.  You also see it in the x86 code, the redundant store actually makes a double to float conversion.  Eliminating the conversion looks difficult in the x86 case so this may well have leaked into the x64 jitter.

Do note that the x64 code runs significantly faster than the x86 code so be sure to set the Platform target to AnyCPU for a simple win.  At least part of that speed up was the optimizer's smarts at hoisting the integer multiplication.

And do make sure to test realistic data, your measurement is fundamentally invalid due to the uninitialized array content.  The difference is much less pronounced with non-zero data in the elements, it makes the division much more expensive.

Also note your bug in the double case, you should not use 1.0f there.

Comment: Interesting.  Wouldn't the "redundant store, convert to float" be there to truncate any extra precision in the double value, to comply with the requirement that such extra precision be eliminated on an explicit conversion?

Comment: Yes, I do think this is the core problem.  The FPU just doesn't like *float* much.  Generating efficient code for it is a devilish black art in general.  Much improved in SSE2.

Comment: Very informative, thanks for the detailed answers. But then I cannot understand why elimination of the writeback (as ZongZhengLi's comment says) the effect disappears? I tried to run on Debug mode to eliminate optimizations when writeback is not needed, and the behavior is very similar to the Release mode.

Comment: If you remove the assignment then the optimizer removes the entire calculation since its result is useless.  Removed code is not slower or faster than removed code.

Comment: I thought about that, so as I said I run also in Debug mode to avoid such optimizations and it made no difference.

Answer (score 3):

From the C# specification:

> Floating-point operations may be performed with higher precision than
>   the result type of the operation. For example, some hardware
>   architectures support an “extended” or “long double” floating-point
>   type with greater range and precision than the double type, and
>   implicitly perform all floating-point operations using this higher
>   precision type. Only at excessive cost in performance can such
>   hardware architectures be made to perform floating-point operations
>   with less precision, and rather than require an implementation to
>   forfeit both performance and precision, C# allows a higher precision
>   type to be used for all floating-point operations. Other than
>   delivering more precise results, this rarely has any measurable
>   effects. However, in expressions of the form x * y / z, where the
>   multiplication produces a result that is outside the double range, but
>   the subsequent division brings the temporary result back into the
>   double range, the fact that the expression is evaluated in a higher
>   range format may cause a finite result to be produced instead of an
>   infinity.

There may be additional instructions required to convert the value to a 32-bit float before storing it in the array.

Additionally, as mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/158953/385844) to one of the questions you link to, the CLI spec requires 64-bit (or 80-bit) values to be truncated in some other circumstances.  That answer also links to additional discussion here:

http://weblog.ikvm.net/PermaLink.aspx?guid=f300c4e1-15b0-45ed-b6a6-b5dc8fb8089e